# Generic wildcards in variable declarations in Scala

Tags: java, generics, scala, covariance, contravariance

In Java I might do this:

```
class MyClass {
    private List<? extends MyInterface> list;

    public void setList(List<MyImpl> l) { list = l; }
}
```

...assuming that (`MyImpl implements MyInterface`) of course.

What is the analog for this in **Scala**, when using a `Buffer`?

```
import java.lang.reflect._
import scala.collection.mutable._

class ScalaClass {
   val list:Buffer[MyInterface]  = null

   def setList(l: Buffer[MyImpl]) = {
     list = l
   }
}
```

This (of course) doesn't compile - but how do I declare the `list` variable in such a way that it does?

**EDIT**; I'm adding a bit more. The difference is obviously something to do with the fact that in Java, generics are *never covariant in T*, whereas in Scala they can be either covariant or not. For example, the Scala class `List` is covariant in T (and necessarily immutable). Therefore the following **will compile**:

```
class ScalaClass {
   val list:List[MyInterface]  = null

   def setList(l: List[MyImpl]) = {
     list = l
   }
}
```

I'm still struggling a bit with the compiler error:

> `Covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in ...`

For example; this compiler error occurs in the class declaration:

```
class Wibble[+T] {
  var some: T = _ //COMPILER ERROR HERE!
 }
```

I'm going to ask a separate question...

Comment: Has this question been answered or is it still open?

Comment: I hadn't noticed your answer as I went on holiday shortly after this. Sorry. I'm pretty sure that I had read that there were "no wildcards in Scala". Was this ever the case? I assume it's not now...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The direct analog to

```
import java.util.List;
List<? extends MyInterface> list;
```

is

```
import java.util.List
var list : List[_ <: MyInterface]  = _;
```

Same deal with Buffer

To answer a comment you made earler, in Java type parameters are always invariant, not covariant.