# Error: Covariant type A occurs in contravariant position

Tags: scala, covariance, contravariance

I was trying to write an immutable `Matrix[A]` class. I want the class to be covariant on `A` but when I put `+` in front of `A` compiler starts complaining about some operations in the class.

Following is a relevant subset of my `Matrix` class (The actual class is some 5 times bigger than the following subset):

```
class Matrix[+A] private(val contents: Vector[Vector[A]])(implicit numericEv: Numeric[A])
    extends ((Int, Int) => A) with Proxy {

  import numericEv._
  import Prelude._

  // delegate `equals` and `hashCode` implementations to `contents`
  override def self = contents

  val nRows: Int = contents.length

  val nColumns: Int = contents(0).length.ensuring { len =>
    contents.forall(_.length == len)        
  }

  def dimensions = (nRows, nColumns)

  def isSquare = nRows == nColumns

  def hasSameOrderAs[B : Numeric](that: Matrix[B]) = this.dimensions == that.dimensions

  def isComformableWith[B : Numeric](that: Matrix[B]) = this.nColumns == that.nRows

  private def assertSameOrder[B : Numeric](that: Matrix[B]) {
    assert(this.hasSameOrderAs(that), "Matrices differ in dimensions.")
  }

  private def assertIsSquare() {
    assert(this.isSquare, "Not a square matrix.")
  }      

  def zipWith[B : Numeric, C : Numeric](that: Matrix[B])(f: (A, B) => C): Matrix[C] = {
    assertSameOrder(that)
    val zippedContents = (contents, that.contents).zipped.map((v1, v2) => (v1, v2).zipped.map(f))
    Matrix(zippedContents)
  }

  def map[B : Numeric](f: A => B): Matrix[B] = {
    Matrix(contents.map(_.map(f)))
  }

  def transpose: Matrix[A] = {
    assertIsSquare()
    Matrix(contents.transpose)
  }

  def +(that: Matrix[A]): Matrix[A] = this.zipWith(that)(_ + _)

  def -(that: Matrix[A]): Matrix[A] = this.zipWith(that)(_ - _)

  def *(scalar: A): Matrix[A] = this.map(_ * scalar)

  def *(that: Matrix[A]): Matrix[A] = {
    assert(this.isComformableWith(that))
    Matrix.tabulate(this.nRows, that.nColumns) { (r, c) =>
      (this(r), that.transpose(c)).zipped.map(_ * _).sum
    }
  }
}

object Matrix {
  def apply[A : Numeric](rows: Vector[A]*): Matrix[A] = Matrix(Vector(rows: _*))

  def apply[A : Numeric](contents: Vector[Vector[A]]): Matrix[A] = new Matrix(contents)

  def tabulate[A : Numeric](nRows: Int, nColumns: Int)(f: (Int, Int) => A): Matrix[A] = {
    Matrix(Vector.tabulate(nRows, nColumns)(f))
  }
}
```

Compiler shows the error "Covariant type A occurs in contravariant position" for the last four operations in the class. I am unable to understand the reason for these errors, and how to get rid of it. Please explain the reason behind these errors and suggest a way to work around them. Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/scala-covariance-contravariance-question

Comment: for the purposes of providing examples, you don't need the code that doesn't generate an error. In other words, [sample code](http://sscce.org/) should be just long enough stand on its own and reproduce the error, but no longer.

Answer (score 8):

The reason for these errors is that it is not type-safe to declare it as you are doing. For instance, it would be possible to do this, otherwise:

```
class A(val x: Int)
class B(x: Int, val y: Int) extends A(x)

object NA extends Numeric[A] {
    def toDouble(x: A): Double = x.x.toDouble
    def toFloat(x: A): Float = x.x.toFloat
    def toLong(x: A): Long = x.x.toLong
    def toInt(x: A): Int = x.x
    def fromInt(x: Int): A = new A(x)
    def negate(x: A): A = new A(-x.x)
    def times(x: A,y: A): A = new A(x.x * y.x)
    def minus(x: A,y: A): A = new A(x.x - y.x)
    def plus(x: A,y: A): A = new A(x.x + y.x)
    def compare(x: A,y: A): Int = implicitly[Numeric[Int]].compare(x.x, y.x)
}

object NB extends Numeric[B] {
    def toDouble(x: B): Double = x.x.toDouble / x.y.toDouble
    def toFloat(x: B): Float = x.x.toFloat / x.y.toFloat
    def toLong(x: B): Long = (x.x / x.y).toLong
    def toInt(x: B): Int = x.x / x.y
    def fromInt(x: Int): B = new B(x, 1)
    def negate(x: B): B = new B(-x.x, x.y)
    def times(x: B,y: B): B = new B(x.x * y.x, x.y * y.y)
    def minus(x: B,y: B): B = new B(x.x * y.y - y.x * x.y, x.y * y.y)
    def plus(x: B,y: B): B = new B(x.x * y.y + y.x * x.y, x.y * y.y)
    def compare(x: B,y: B): Int = implicitly[Numeric[Int]].compare(x.x * x.y, y.x * y.y)
}

val mb = Matrix.tabulate(10, 10)((x, y) => new B(x, y))
def f(m: Matrix[A]) = {
  val ma = Matrix.tabulate(m.nRows, m.nColumns)((x, y) => 1)
  m + ma
}
f(mb)
```

Note that `m + ma` could not work, since `m.+` expects an object of type `B`. If Scala allowed you to write it the way you did, though, this would be allowed.

The common way to avoid this problem is to write the method like this:

```
def +[B >: A](that: Matrix[B])(implicit num: Numeric[B]): Matrix[B] = this.zipWith(that)(B.plus)
```