# Why can't this simple example be compiled?

Tags: scala, types

This a very simple scala sample, but it can't be compiled:

```
abstract class Box[+A] {
    var value: A = _
}
```

The error is:

```
covariant type A occurs in contravariant position in type A of parameter of setter value_=
```

What I want the class to do is:

```
class StringBox extends Box[String]
class DateBox extends Box[Date]

object Testbox {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val list = ListBuffer[Box[Any]]()
        val str = new StringBox
        str.value = "abc"
        val date = new DateBox
        date.value = new Date
        list += str
        list += date
        println(list)
    }
}
```

Comment: What would happen if you added this code: `list[1].value = "fail"`? "fail" is an `Any`, and list is a `ListBuffer[Box[Any]]` so that should be valid. But then, the element in the list is a `Box[Date]`. Ooops, we just assigned a string to a date!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not compile because it is incorrect. If scala were to allow you to do it, then you could violate type safety. For example:

```
import scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance

abstract class Box[+A] {
    var value: A  @uncheckedVariance = _
}

class StringBox extends Box[String]
val sb = new StringBox; sb.value = "abc"
val sa: Box[Any] = sb
sa.value = 5
println(sb.value.length)
```

Comment: @Daniel Thank you for the answer. I did not know about @uncheckedVariance

Comment: @Misha You shouldn't use it, though. If Scala tells you something is wrong, then something is most likely wrong.

Comment: @Daniel, could you give me a correct sample which I can set values to `StringBox` and `DateBox`?

Comment: @Freewind I don't understand what do you mean by "correct". The code here is compilable, and you can replace `5` with a `new Date` just as well.

Comment: I mean, is it possible not use `@uncheckedVariance`, but let `Box` do the same thing?

Comment: @Freewind There are ways to get around variance, but this is one specific example of what is precisely what shouldn't and can't be done. If you want to expose `value` as a `var` to be used outside the class, then it cannot be covariant.

Answer (score 4):

*Mutable* classes (and your class `Box` is mutable) cannot be covariant in the type of their mutable field. You can make `Box` immutable though

```
abstract class Box[+A] { val value: A }
```

Comment: how do I make my `StringBox` and `DateBox` with this `Box` you provided? I can't set value to them

Answer (score 2):

Please see the answer to this question:
[Scala covariance / contravariance question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/scala-covariance-contravariance-question)

Comment: thank you, I have read that, but that does not resolve my problem: I need to set values, so I can't use `val`