# Scala subtyping + implicit conversion problem

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, scalaz, subtyping

I am trying to do something with monads in scala using scalaz library, and have some trouble making it work nicely with subtyping.

I have started with defining my own monad. Let it be an identity monad for the sake of simplicity:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

class Id[+A] (val value : A) { }

implicit object IdMonad extends Monad[Id] {
    override def pure[A](a : => A) = new Id(a)
    override def bind[A, B](a : Id[A], f : A => Id[B]) = f(a.value)
}
```

Next, I have extended it with some additional functionality:

```
class ExtendedId[A] (value : A, val printer : A => String) extends Id[A](value) { }
```

With this additional functionality, `ExtendedId` is not a monad anymore.

Now I want to use the object of type `ExtendedId[A]` as an `Id[A]`:

```
def increment1(v : ExtendedId[Int]) : Id[Int] = {
    for(v <- v) yield v + 1;
    //    ^
    //  error: could not find implicit value for parameter t:  scalaz.Functor[test.package.ExtendedId]
}
```

Note that I understand that since `ExtendedId` is not a monad, the best I can get as an output is `Id[Int]`, and I am okay with that! But unfortunately, that code still does not compile.

However, this one does:

```
def asId[A](a : ExtendedId[A]) : Id[A] = a

def increment2(v : ExtendedId[Int]) {
    for(v <- asId(v)) yield v + 1;
}
```

Here, `asId` function does nothing more than upcasting its argument to from `ExtendedId[A]` to `Id[A]`. It seems that it should be completely redundant, but it is not.

Why is this happening? There does exist an implicit conversion from `Id[A]` to an object containing `map` and there obviously does exist a trivial implicit conversion from `ExtendedId[A]` to `Id[A]`. So, why is the compiler unable combine them?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Scalaz does not define `Monad` as being covariant in its first type argument (or, more precisely, *type constructor* argument). In other words, a `Monad[A]` is considered a different type altogether from a `Monad[B]`, even if `A <: B`. ([More on covariance and contravariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/scala-covariance-contravariance-question/674090#674090))

There are good reasons why `Monad` is invariant. One is: if you make the compiler believe that a `Monad[Id]` is actually also valid as a `Monad[ExtendedId]`, you're bound to run into problems at some point — one of them is that wherever `pure` is called, the compiler will infer an `ExtendedId` result type, whereas only an `Id` would be returned.

I *think* there isn't a technique to fix this cleanly — other than defining a `Monad[ExtendedId]`, or something like

```
implicit def idMonad[A[_] <: Id[_]]: Monad[A] = ...
```

which indeed is able to return a proper monad for all subclasses of `Id`.

Comment: I can not define a `Monad[ExtendedId]` because `ExtendedId` is not a monad -- there is no useful implementation of `bind` for `ExtendedId` (`printer` value makes it impossible). What I can do is to cast `ExtendedId[A]` to `Id[A]`, but I don't understand why the compiler does not do that implicitly. I mean, upcasting is the mother of all implicit conversions and still it is not performed implicitly.

Comment: The notation `[A <: Id]` seems to be invalid because the `Id` type constructor needs parameters. And `[A[_] <: Id[_]]` complains about some "illegal cyclic reference involving type A".

Comment: @Rostor You're right, I had messed up my type parameters. I've edited my answer. As I wrote, the compiler doesn't cast things the way you describe because `Monad` is not covariant; i.e., the definition of `Monad` explicitly says, in practice, “a `Monad[A]` is not a `Monad[B]` even if `B <: A`.” If you explicitly cast, you're telling the compiler that you know it's safe for you — but it's not in the general case of Scalaz monads.

Comment: "a `Monad[A]` is not a `Monad[B]`" -- I am fine with that. I don't want `Monad[B]`. What I want is an upcast (which is always safe and normally implicit) from B[V] to A[V] before even trying to obtain a `Monad` instance.

Comment: The code `idMonad[A <: Id[_]]: Monad[A]` still can't compile because this way `A` is not a type constructor, but `Monad` requires one. I've managed to compile [A[X] <: Id[X]], but with scala 2.7.7 (not too recent, I know) a function defined like this crashes in runtime, indicating a bug in the compiler.

Comment: @Rostor Darn, I should pay better attention to what I write. It compiles fine now (tested it on the REPL v2.8.1, didn't get your “illegal cyclic reference involving type A”).