# java cast from List<B> to List<A> where B extends A

Tags: java, types, casting, covariance

is this possible? if not, why isn't this possible in Java?

```
interface B extends A {}
public List<B> getList();
List<A> = getList(); // Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<B> to List<A>
```

I think the topic I'm looking for is "covariant types" as [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx#InterfaceCovariantTypeParameters) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/scala-covariance-contravariance-question), but its murky and it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Why exactly is `getList()` declared to return `List<B>` in first place? Can't it be `List<A>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is `List<Dog>` a subclass of `List<Animal>`? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitl)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an intuitive example of how this can make things go horribly wrong:

```
interface B extends A {}
List<B> blist=new List<B>();
List<A> alist=blist;
alist.add(new A()); //should be ok, right?
B b = blist.get(0); //fail: even though blist is a List<B>, it now has an A in it
```

Comment: hmm. if i silence the compiler with `List<? extends A>`, it seems that this problem still exists? edit: no, i speculate error moves to L4. cool.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
List<? extends A> = getList()
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't do this is that A and B are not the same, you have specified getList returns a List of B (not a super class or a sub class)