# How do I configure the Column names in a Scala Table?

Tags: scala

I am writing a Scala program to manage a database, and have drawn all of the data into a 2-dimensional ArrayBuffer where row 0 is the column names, and the subsequent rows contain the info for each entry in the table.
When trying to put this into a Table, ho=w do I go about assigning the Column headers?

Syntax suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Pseudocode:

```
Data=ArrayBuffer()
Data(0)={"Name","Birthday","ID"}
Data(1)={"Bob", "07/19/1986", "2354"}
Data(2)={"Sue", "05/07/1980", "2355"}
Data(3)={"Joe", "08/12/1992", "2356"}
Data(4)={"Jim", "11/20/1983", "2357"}
```

I want to put this into a Table where Data(0) describes the column headers, and the subsequent rows describe rows in the table, but I can't figure out how to set the row headers.

Comment: You probably need to add additional information to this question. I think even pseudo code on what you're trying to do may help.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to put data in a Table is to use its constructor:

```
new Table (rowData: Array[Array[Any]], columnNames: Seq[_])
```

The slightly tricky thing here is that arrays are not covariant (see [Why doesn't the example compile, aka how does (co-, contra-, and in-) variance work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/scala-covariance-contravariance-question/674090#674090)), which means that an `Array[String]` is **not** a subtype of `Array[Any]`. So you need some way of turning one into the other: a `map` does the job.

Also, for the column names to show, you need to put the table in a ScrollPane.

```
import swing._
import collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object Demo extends SimpleSwingApplication {

  val data = ArrayBuffer(
    Array("Name","Birthday","ID"),
    Array("Bob", "07/19/1986", "2354"),
    Array("Sue", "05/07/1980", "2355")
  )

  def top = new MainFrame {
    contents = new ScrollPane {
      contents = new Table(
        data.tail.toArray map (_.toArray[Any]),
        data.head
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Will give you a table:

[image: table]

Edit: you can also use a cast: `data.tail.toArray.asInstanceOf[Array[Array[Any]]]`, which is more efficient than mapping.

Comment: So, that sounds like exactly what I want, but I am using and array of ArrayBuffers instead of an array of Arrays...  I am not sure if that is the problem, but when I type in your code to display my buffer, I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error, that I can't understand, and I am not sure how is being drawn from that code.  Is this that I am using ArrayBuffers, or am I missing something else?

Comment: @Museless The code above will work just as well with ArrayBuffers, although the point of ArrayBuffers is that they're expandable, so there's no point using them for a fixed number of columns. There is no way the code above can give you an out of bounds error. The exception should tell you which line it's occurring on.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are talking of swing, if you put your table inside a scrollpane and create your table model based on the array buffer shown, the first row will be taken as column names by default.

Comment: Not sure how to go about settung up a table model.  My few feeble attempts at doing so have led to alot of Code-Not-Running syndrome.  What is the syntax for this in 2.8?  \n right now, I am simply updating the cells in a for-loop, because I haven't been able to find an easier way to update the data in the table, but this still leaves me with "A", "B", "C", "D", etc for my column headers

Comment: you can refer to [this code](https://github.com/asinghal/SlateIDE/blob/master/src/net/slate/gui/ResultsTabbedPane.scala) for some examples.