# How do I algorithmically instantiate and manipulate a multidimensional array in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, multidimensional-array, instantiation

I am trying to wrote a program to manage a Database through a Scala Gui, and have been running into alot of trouble formatting my data in such a way as to input it into a Table and have the Column Headers populate.  To do this, I have been told I would need to use an Array[Array[Any]] instead of an ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[String]] as I have been using.

My problem is that the way I am trying to fill these arrays is modular: I am trying to use the same function to draw from different tables in a MySQL database, each of which has a different number of columns and entries.

I have been able to (I think) define a 2-D array with

```
val Data = new Array[Array[String]](numColumns)(numRows)
```

but I haven't found any ways of editing individual cells in this new array.

```
Data(i)(j)=Value  //or
Data(i,j)=Value
```

do not work, and give me errors about "Update" functionality

I am sure this can't possibly be as complicated as I have been making it, so what is the easy way of managing these things in this language?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to read your data into an Array of Arrays - you just need to convert it to that format when you feed it to the `Table` constuctor - which is easy, as demonstrated my answer to your other question: [How do I configure the Column names in a Scala Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8043669/770361)

If you're creating a 2D array, the idiom you want is

```
val data = Array.ofDim[String](numColumms, numRows)
```

(There is also `new Array[String](numColumns, numRows)`, but that's deprecated.)

You access element (i, j) of an Array `data` with `data(i)(j)` (remember they start from 0).

But in general you should avoid mutable collections (like Array, ArrayBuffer) unless there's a good reason. Try `Vector` instead.

Without knowing the format in which you're retrieving data from the database it's not possible to say how to put it into a collection.

**Update**:

You can alternatively put the type information on the left hand side, so the following are equivalent (decide for yourself which you prefer):

```
val a: Array[Array[String]] = Array.ofDim(2,2)
val a = Array.ofDim[String](2,2)
```

To explain the syntax for accessing / updating elements: as in Java, a multi-dimensional array is just an array of arrays. So here, `a(i)` is element i of a, which an `Array[String]`, and so `a(i)(j)` is element j of that array, which is a `String`.

Answer (score 3):

Luigi's answer is great, but I'd like to shed some light on why your code isn't working.

```
val Data = new Array[Array[String]](numColumns)(numRows)
```

does not do what you expect it to do. The `new Array[Array[String]](numColumns)` part does create an array of array of strings with numColumns entries, with all entries (arrys of strings) being null, and returns it. The following `(numRows)` then just calls the `apply` function on that returned object, which returns the `numRows`th entry in that list, which is null.

You can try that out in the scala REPL: When you input

```
new Array[Array[String]](10)(9)
```

you get this as output:

```
res0: Array[String] = null
```

Luigi's solution, instead

```
Array.ofDim[String](2,2)
```

does the right thing:

```
res1: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(null, null), Array(null, null))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's rather ugly, but you can update a multidimensional array with `update`

```
> val data = Array.ofDim[String](2,2)
data: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(null, null), Array(null, null))
> data(0).update(0, "foo")
> data
data: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(foo, null), Array(null, null))
```

Not sure about the efficiency of this technique.

Answer (score 1):

Luigi's answer is great, but I just wanted to point out another way of initialising an Array that is more idiomatic/functional – using `tabulate`. This takes a function that takes the array cell coordinates as input and produces the cell value:

```
scala> Array.tabulate[String](4, 4) _
res0: (Int, Int) => String => Array[Array[String]] = <function1>

scala> val data = Array.tabulate(4, 4) {case (x, y) => x * y }
data: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 0, 0, 0), Array(0, 1, 2, 3), Array(0, 2, 4, 6), Array(0, 3, 6, 9))
```