# Table headers disappear without ScrollPane

Tags: swing, scala, scala-swing

I wrote the following simple code to test scala.swing.Table:

```
// java version "1.7.0_01"
// Scala code runner version 2.9.1.final
// Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit
import scala.swing._

object TableHeaderVisible extends SimpleSwingApplication {
    override def top = new MainFrame {
        preferredSize = new Dimension(300, 200)
//      contents = new ScrollPane(table)
        contents = table
    }
    lazy val table = new Table(model, Seq("fruit", "animal")) // with Scrollable
    lazy val model = Array(
            Array("orange", "dog"),
            Array("apple",  "cat")).asInstanceOf[Array[Array[Any]]]
}
```

This produces no table headers, "fruit" and "animal".

Why?

I can do that with

```
contents = new ScrollPane(table)
```

not

```
contents = table.
```

But whether using `ScrollPane` or not should not affect whether table headers are visible or not, I think.

Is there any incorrect code ... in my code? or in `scala.swing._` library?

Or is there any reason to justify invisible header[s] without ScrollPane?

Comment: not "does not affect"
but "should not affect"

Comment: perhaps related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8043669/770361

Comment: there's still Swing? Far out...

Comment: javax.swing.JTable has the same problem.

And scala.swing._ wraps javax.swing.*.

So, this problem may sound natual.

scala-swing cannot overcome java-swing?

Comment: I'm newbie at scala-swing. Do I expect toooo much scala-swing?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know anything about scala.

In the underlying Swing, the reason is that there are two distinct components - JTable and an optional JTableHeader. While the header is configured to use the same TableColumnModel as the table itself (plus some wiring) always, its actual addition to the component hierarchy is managed by the table only if the table is contained in a scrollPane. If it is not in a scrollPane, the client code is responsible for inserting it where it makes most sense, f.i. in a panel above the table. In fact, there is nothing the table itself can reasonably do in that case, the surroundings can differ wildly

Answer (score 0):

Swing was originally written for Java, which definitely does *not* have lazy vals. My bet is that if you avoid lazy vals, the problem will disappear. If Scala actually intended to support lazy vals for the swing library, then this might be a bug.

Comment: I don't think it's anything to do with lazy vals.