# Table missing headers

Tags: scala, swing

I'm using a custom `TableModel` that has a companion custom `ColumnModel`. Below is the code for the panel that it is on.

The table works great and I can add and remove columns without any trouble but the headers are never displayed. How would I fix that?

```
val panel = new BorderPanel() {
  var sourceLabel = new Label("No file chosen")
  layout(sourceLabel) = North

  var tableModel = new LogRecordTableModel
  var dataTable = new Table {
    model = tableModel
    peer.setColumnModel(tableModel.columnModel)
  }

  val scrollPane = new ScrollPane(dataTable)

  layout(scrollPane) = Center

  layout(controlStrip) = South

  openAction.setParent(this)
  listenTo(openAction)
  reactions += {
    case f:FileChosen =>
      tableModel.setSource(f.file)
      updateFile(f.file)
  }

  listenTo(previousAction)
  reactions += {
    case PREVIOUS =>
      tableModel.previous()
      updateButtons()
  }

  listenTo(nextAction)
  reactions += {
    case NEXT =>
      tableModel.next()
      updateButtons()
  }

  def updateFile(file: File) {
    sourceLabel = new Label(file.getName)
    layout(sourceLabel) = North
    Thread.sleep(100)
    updateButtons()

    revalidate()
    main.repaint()
  }

  def updateButtons() {
    nextButton.enabled = tableModel.hasNext
    previousButton.enabled = tableModel.hasPrevious
  }

  def updateTypeControl() {
    println("[$lessanonymous$greater.updateTypeControl] enter.")
    typeControl.selection.item(tableModel, typeValues.selection.item)
  }
}
```

Comment: Glancing over http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2190 it looks as if you do the right thing ... maybe the links in the thread will help you.

Comment: Can you please post more of the code such as adding to frame, usually wrapping in a ScrollPane fixes the problem.

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8043669/770361 Any use?

Comment: @GarrettHall - added the code for the panel. LuigiPlinge - Unfortunately, that question was not helpful to me for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the column model swing drops the header and it needs to be reset, give this a try:

```
var dataTable = new Table {
  model = tableModel
  peer.setColumnModel(tableModel.columnModel)

  for( i <- 0 until peer.getColumnCount) {
    peer.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setHeaderValue(tableModel.getColumnName(i))
  }
}
```

Comment: Except for the loop limit being off, that does it! Thank you.