# Why is Function[-A1,...,+B] not about allowing any supertypes as parameters?

Tags: function, scala, covariance, contravariance

I believe one can define covariance (at least, for objects) as 'the ability to use a value of a narrower (sub) type in place of a value of some wider (super) type', and that contravariance is the exact opposite of this.

Apparently, Scala functions are instances of Function[-A1,...,+B] for contravariant parameter types A1, etc. and covariant return type, B. While this is handy for subtyping on Functions, shouldn't the above definition mean I can pass any supertypes as parameters?

Please advise where I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Covariance and contravariance are qualities of *the class* not qualities of *the parameters*.  (They are qualities that depend on the parameters, but they make statements about the class.)

So, `Function1[-A,+B]` means that *a function* that takes superclasses of `A` can be viewed as a subclass of *the original function*.

Let's see this in practice:

```
class A
class B extends A
val printB: B => Unit = { b => println("Blah blah") }
val printA: A => Unit = { a => println("Blah blah blah") }
```

Now suppose you require a function that knows how to print a `B`:

```
def needsB(f: B => Unit, b: B) = f(b)
```

You could pass in `printB`.  But you could *also* pass in `printA`, since it also knows how to print `B`s (and more!), just as if `A => Unit` was a subclass of `B => Unit`.  This is exactly what contravariance means.  It doesn't mean you can pass `Option[Double]` into `printB` and get anything but a compile-time error!

(Covariance is the other case: `M[B] <: M[A]` if `B <: A`.)

Comment: Thank you, that was very clear. Attempting to (re)define: 'co/contra-variance are properties dictating the subtype relation between types, subject to the nature of the same relation between their component types'. Abstract, I know, but I prefer to have a definition devoid of examples (although yours was very helpful).

Comment: thanks for the -A, could you explain why is +B  in the  Function1[-A,+B]

Comment: @liango - Anexplanation by example: if you return a `String` you certainly return an `Object`, so `... => String` must be a subclass of `... => Object`.  That's what `+B` signifies.

Answer (score 35):

This question is old, but I think a clearer explanation is to invoke the Liskov Substitution Principle: everything that's true about a superclass should be true of all its subclasses. You should be able to do with a SubFoo everything that you can do with a Foo, and maybe more.

Suppose we have Calico <: Cat <: Animal, and Husky <: Dog <: Animal. Let's look at a `Function[Cat, Dog]`. What statements are true about this? There are two:

(1) You can pass in any Cat (so any subclass of Cat)

(2) You can call any Dog method on the returned value

So does `Function[Calico, Dog] <: Function[Cat, Dog]` make sense? No, statements that are true of the superclass are not true of the subclass, namely statement (1). You can't pass in any Cat to a Function that only takes Calico cats.

But does `Function[Animal, Dog] <: Function[Cat, Dog]` make sense? Yes, all statements about the superclass are true of the subclass. I can still pass in any Cat -- in fact I can do even more than that, I can pass in any Animal -- and I can call all Dog methods on the returned value.

So `A <: B` implies `Function[B, _] <: Function[A, _]`

Now, does `Function[Cat, Husky] <: Function[Cat, Dog]` make sense? Yes, all statements about the superclass are true of the subclass; I can still pass in a Cat, and I can still call all Dog methods on the returned value -- in fact I can do even more than that, I can call all Husky methods on the returned value.

But does `Function[Cat, Animal] <: Function[Cat, Dog]` make sense? No, statements that are true of the superclass are not true of the subclass, namely statement (2). I can't call all methods available on Dog on the returned value, only the ones available on Animal.

So with a `Function[Animal, Husky]` I can do everything I can do with a `Function[Cat, Dog]`: I can pass in any Cat, and I can call all of the Dog methods on the returned value. And I can do even more: I can pass in other animals, and I can call of the methods available on Husky that aren't available on Dog. So it makes sense: `Function[Animal, Husky] <: Function[Cat, Dog]`. The first type parameter can be replaced with a superclass, the second with a subclass.

Comment: How can I check <: programmatically with those examples you gave?

Comment: @CaptainObvious: Create a method that takes a `Function[Cat, Dog]` as an argument. Try to pass in a `Function[Cat, Animal]` and you'll get a compiler error. Try to pass in a `Function[Calico, Animal]` and you'll also get a compiler error. Those aren't subclasses of `Function[Cat, Dog]`.

Then try to pass in a `Function[Animal, Dog]` and that'll work fine. Try to pass in a `Function[Cat, Husky]` and that'll also work fine. Those _are_ subclasses of the `Function[Cat, Dog]`.

Comment: Very good explanation! May be considered as the answer for both `variance` and `Liskov principle` topics

Answer (score 6):

There are two separate ideas at work here. One is using subtyping to allow more specific arguments to be passed to a function (called *subsumption*). The other is how to check subtyping on functions themselves.

For type-checking the arguments to a function, you only have to check that the given arguments are subtypes of the declared argument types. The result also has to be a subtype of the declared type. This is where you actually check subtyping.

The contra/co-variance of the parameters & result only factor in when you want to check whether a given *function type* is a subtype of another function type. So if a parameter has type `Function[A1, ... ,B]`, then the argument has to be a function type `Function[C1, ..., D]` where `A1 <: C1 ...` and `D <: B`.

This reasoning isn't specific to Scala and applies to other statically-typed languages with subtyping.

Answer (score 1):

A simplified explanation

```
class A
class B extends A
val printA: A => Unit = { a => println("Blah blah blah") }
printA(new A())   //"Blah blah blah"
printA(new B())   //"Blah blah blah"
```

contravariance rule:

If `B` is a subtype of `A`, then `printA[A]` is a subtype of `printA[B]`

Since `printA[B]` is the superclass, we can use `printA(new B())`

Answer (score -1):

Covariant means converting from wider (super) to narrower (sub). For example, we have two class: one is animal (super) and the other one is cat then using covariant, we can convert animal to cat.

Contra-variant is just the opposite of covariant, which means cat to animal.

Invariant means it's unable to convert.