# Why are input parameters contravariant in methods?

Tags: scala, covariance, contravariance

Here's some code from [this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/lower-type-bounds.html) tutorial:

```
case class ListNode[+T](h: T, t: ListNode[T]) {
  def head: T = h
  def tail: ListNode[T] = t
  def prepend(elem: T): ListNode[T] =
    ListNode(elem, this)
}
```

The tutorial says:

> Unfortunately, this program does not compile, because a covariance
>   annotation is only possible if the type variable is used only in
>   covariant positions. Since type variable T appears as a parameter type
>   of method prepend, this rule is broken.

How is `T` not in a covariant position in `predend`, and the other `T` references (`def head: T = h` and `def tail: ListNode[T] = t`), apparently, are covariant?

What I'm asking is why `T` in `prepend` is not covariant. This is certainly not covered in [Why is Function[-A1,...,+B] not about allowing any supertypes as parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10603982/1305344), which seems to be what others have directed me to read.

Comment: It is as written. In the other two methods `T` is in a contravariant position, it is _only_ in the return type, while for `prepend` it is also in the parameter (`elem: T`), so it can only be invariant.

Comment: Consider the following example: `trait Fruit; class Apple extends Fruit; class Pear extends Fruit`. Assume `ListNode` is covariant, so `ListNode[Apple]` is also a `ListNode[Fruit]`: `val node: ListNode[Fruit] = ListNode[Apple](new Apple(), null)`. Now if you `prepend` with another `Fruit`, `node.prepend(new Pear())`, you would clearly not get a (typesafe) `ListNode[Apple]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Input parameters of methods are not in covariant positions but contravariant positions. Only the return types of methods are in covariant positions.

If your defination of `ListNode` class **were** OK, then I could write code like this:

```
val list1: ListNode[String] = ListNode("abc", null)
val list2: ListNode[Any] = list1  // list2 and list1 are the same thing
val list3: ListNode[Int] = list2.prepend(1) // def prepend(elem: T): ListNode[T]
val x: Int = list3.tail.head // ERROR, x in fact is "abc"
```

See, if arguments **were** covariant positions, then a container could always hold values of another type which has the same ancestor of its real type, and this is definitely **WRONG**!

So, referring to the source code of [scala.collection.immutable.List.::](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L111), your class should be defined as this:

```
case class ListNode[+T](h: T, t: ListNode[T]) {
  def head: T = h
  def tail: ListNode[T] = t
  def prepend[A >: T](elem: A): ListNode[A] = ListNode(elem, this)
}
```

The argument type `A` is a new type parameter which is lower bounded to `T`.

Comment: Regarding line 3 in your first snippet. Since `list2.prepend()` returns a `ListNode[Any]`, and `Any` is a supertype of `Int`, how could this successfully be assigned to `list3: ListNode[Int]`? ListNode is covariant, not contravariant, so val `list3: ListNode[Int] = list2.prepend(1)` should fail, should it not?

Comment: You're right. The example is invalid: it attempts to find a contradiction where there is none, because as we know, covariant immutable `List[+A]` from the standard library works just fine (as long as you get the generics right). If you wanted to construct a good counterexample, you'd have to find something that *actually breaks*, not something that *actually works*.

Answer (score 2):

An example:

```
val dogList = ListNode[Dog](...)
val animal = Animal()
val dog = Dog()

dogList.prepend(dog) //works
dogList.prepend(animal) //fails
```

covariance means that you can use a ListNode[Dog] like a ListNode[Animal]

but:

```
//if compiler would allow it
val animalList: ListNode[Animal] = dogList
animalList.prepend(dog) //works
animalList.prepend(animal) //would fail, but you expect an animallist to accept any animal
```