# Contravariant method arguments in Scala

Tags: scala

The top answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365846/why-are-input-parameters-contravariant-in-methods/30367360#comment100164104_30367360) explains why method arguments are contravariant. The author says that if this would compile:

```
case class ListNode[+T](h: T, t: ListNode[T]) {
  def head: T = h
  def tail: ListNode[T] = t
  def prepend(elem: T): ListNode[T] =
    ListNode(elem, this)
}
```

Then this would be okay:

```
val list1: ListNode[String] = ListNode("abc", null)
val list2: ListNode[Any] = list1  // list2 and list1 are the same thing
val list3: ListNode[Int] = list2.prepend(1) // def prepend(elem: T): ListNode[T]
```

Note that I have removed the last row of the original snippet.

My thought process is the following:

1. On line 1, a `ListNode[String]` called `list1` is assigned a new `ListNode(someString, null)`. Nothing strange here. `list1` is not a `ListNode[String]`.
2. On line 2, a `ListNode[Any]` gets assigned `list1`. This is fine because `ListNode` is covariant and `Any` is a supertype of `String`.
3. On line 3, the `prepend` method of `list2` is called. Since `list2` is a `ListNode[Any]`, `list2.prepend()` should return a `ListNode[Any]`. But the result of the method call is assigned to a `ListNode[Int]`. This can not possibly compile because `Int` is a **subtype** of `Any` and `ListNode` is NOT contravariant!

Have I misunderstood something? How can the author claim this would ever compile?

Comment: I think you might be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37334674/why-method-defined-like-consb-av-b-accepts-argument-of-type-which-is-n) and its answer.

Answer (score -1):

Let consider what will happen if we define as below:

```
case class ListNode[+T](h: T, t: ListNode[T]) {
  def head: T = h
  def tail: ListNode[T] = t
  def prepend(elem: T): ListNode[T] =
    ListNode(elem, this)
}
```

If you look into `prepend` method, it take `T` (which is type parameter of ListNode) as parameter and return `ListNode[T]`, simple as it is. Now, let elaborate the usage:

```
val list1: ListNode[String] = ListNode("abc", null)
```

In above case, `String` is supertype of `null`, and since `ListNode` is defined `covarient`, it is correct.

```
val list2: ListNode[Any] = list1
```

In above second case, `ListNode[String]` is assigned to `ListNode[Any]` since `Any` is supertype of `String` which is also correct.

```
val list3: ListNode[Int] = list2.prepend(1)
```

Finally in above third case, what we are doing is prepending `1` which is `Int`. If you look into method `prepend(elem: T): ListNode[T]`, we are passing `Int` as type of `elem` value and its returning `ListNode` of type `T`; in this case, `ListNode` of type `Int`. Hence, value returned from invoking `list2.prepend(1)` is of type `ListNode[Int]`. So, above execution for `list3` is also possible (and correct theoritically).

However, in scala, you cannot define `def prepend(elem: T): ListNode[T]` in case of `covariant` type (**you will get compilation error**) and hence you will be never able to do `val list3: ListNode[Int] = list2.prepend(1)`. But instead you can use lower-bounds as below:

```
case class ListNode[+T](h: T, t: ListNode[T]) {
  def head: T = h
  def tail: ListNode[T] = t
  def prepend[U<:T](elem: U): ListNode[U] =
    ListNode[U](elem, this)
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Consider the `prepend` method in isolation:

```
def prepend(elem: T): ListNode[T]
```

This signature means that if you give it a `T` you get `ListNode[T]`. If you give it `Int` you get `ListNode[Int]` so the assignment that you are questioning is perfectly valid.

Also remember that the author is saying that this version of `ListNode` **doesn't** compile, so it is a hypothetical situation.

Comment: I think this is a good answer. Why is it downvoted? Is something incorrect?

Comment: @Sahand The signature is not `def prepend[T](elem: T): ListNode[T]`, it's `def prepend(elem: T): ListNode[T]`. The type parameter `T` is bound in the enclosing class, it is not bound for each new `elem`. If `T` is bound to `Any`, and you give it `elem: Int <: Any`, you get a `ListNode[Any]` back, not `ListNode[Int]`, so the first paragraph seems invalid. The last sentence is kind-of true, though: "from falsehood, anything follows".

Comment: So in that case, I was right? `val list3: ListNode[Int] = list2.prepend(1)` will not compile?

Comment: @Sahand Yes, you are right, it wouldn't compile anyway. But that's not the point. The point is that if e.g. a mutable `HashSet[+A]` with method `+=(elem: A)` were covariant, then it would lead to unsoundness: `import scala.collection.mutable.HashSet ;

val h: HashSet[String] = HashSet.empty ;
val g: HashSet[Any] = h.asInstanceOf[HashSet[Any]] /* pretend it's covariant */ ;
g += 42 ;
val s: String = h.head // Class cast exception`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is it true that in your example `h` and `g` are the same object in memory?

Comment: @Sahand Yes, the assignment says essentially: `g = h`, all the type annotations and `asInstanceOf`s are for the type checker only.

Comment: Note that the second issue raised by @AndreyTyukin is only a problem for mutable types, whereas this `ListNode` implementation is immutable.