# Scala type inference failing to infer types of a generic function

Tags: scala, generics, types, tuples, partialfunction

I have the following code

`def sendMoney[T <: MoneyType](fn: T => Future[T], input: T): Unit`

which is called this way

```
case x: Any => (sendMoney(_, _).tupled(x match {
  case c: HoldsMoney => (createHold(_: HoldsMoney), c: HoldsMoney)
  case r: ReserveMoney => (createReserve(_: ReserveMoney), r: ReserveMoney)
})
```

`HoldsMoney` and `ReserveMoney` have the base type of `MoneyType`.

Scala compiler is throwing the following error.

`missing parameter type for expanded function`

Note, this works if

```
x match {
  case c: HoldsMoney => sendMoney(createHold(_: HoldsMoney), c)
  case r: ReserveMoney => sendMoney(createReserve(_: ReserveMoney), r)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider the type of

```
x match {
  case c: HoldsMoney => (createHold(_: HoldsMoney), c: HoldsMoney)
  case r: ReserveMoney => (createReserve(_: ReserveMoney), r: ReserveMoney)
}
```

The type of `createHold(_: HoldsMoney)` is `HoldsMoney => Future[HoldsMoney]` and the type of `createReserve(_: ReserveMoney)` is `ReserveMoney => Future[ReserveMoney]`.

Because functions are contravariant in their argument type, the common type of those two functions can only be `Nothing => Future[MoneyType]`. So the type of the whole `match` is `(Nothing => Future[MoneyType], MoneyType)` which doesn't conform to `sendMoney`'s argument type.

So the problem is that it's impossible to have a suitable common type for different combinations of `sendMoney`'s arguments.

Comment: Nice. But why isn't the common type as `MoneyType => Future[MoneyType]` . They have a common base class afterall

Comment: @FaizHalde Well, `HoldsMoney <: MoneyType`, `Future[HoldsMoney] <: Future[MoneyType]` (`Future` is covariant), but as I've mentioned `Function` is contravariant in its argument type, and so `HoldsMoney => Future[HoldsMoney]` is NOT a subtype of `MoneyType => Future[MoneyType]`. It may be counterintuitive, but it's actually quite natural when you think about it. Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603982/why-is-function-a1-b-not-about-allowing-any-supertypes-as-parameters

Comment: Yes. The confusion is cleared now! Thanks. Seems like a impossibility to me

Answer (score 0):

I think your goal is to refactor arguments creation for `sendMoney` and to pass them using `tupled`.
I guess missing parts of your codes, and remove type bounds for simplicity.

```
def sendMoney(fn: (MoneyType) => Future[MoneyType], input: MoneyType): Unit = println("sendMoney")

def createHold(moneyType: MoneyType): Future[MoneyType] = ???
def createReserve(moneyType: MoneyType): Future[MoneyType] = ???

(sendMoney _).tupled(x match {
  case c: HoldsMoney => (createHold, c)
  case r: ReserveMoney => (createReserve, r)
})
```