# Typed programming language

Tags: programming-languages, subtype, typed

In designing a typed programming language with subtypes, you need
 to decide when a function type `A->B` is a subtype of a function type `C->D`.

For example, I know that `A <= B` to indicate that **A** is a subtype of **B**

When is it or is it possible `A->B <= C->D` ?

Any help explaining this would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's a very good question. An intuitive answer would be that `A<=C` and `B<=D` conditions are not enough for `A->B <= C->D`, since not all the possible `A->B` types would make sense.

Comment: This answers your question, but you need to look up "contravariance" and "covariance" to understand it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10604305/1292784 . Basically, if function `f`'s signature takes a function `C->D` as an input, you can give it any function `g` that accepts the instances of `C` provided by `f`, and that returns values that `f` can treat as instances of `D`. Thus `A->B <= C->D` if `C<=A` and `B<=D`.