# Understanding the scala syntax about high order function

Tags: scala

I am new to scala , I need to understand what is going on with below code snippet more specifically the sampleFunc val:

```
val sampleFunc: Seq[Row] => (Int, Long, Boolean, Row, String) = (mem: Seq[Row]) => {
                                //some code
                      (a1,b1,c1,d1,e1) // returning the value
                  }

spark.udf.register("sampleUDF", udf(sampleFunc,
  StructType(
    Seq(
      StructField(a, IntegerType),
      StructField(b, LongType),
      StructField(c, BooleanType),
      StructField(d, StructType(schema.fields)),
      StructField(e, StringType)
    )
  )))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I see that in code snippet used `Spark`, but let's omit this and just take a look into `sampleFunc`. So everything quite simple:
Next constitutions declares function itself:

```
val sampleFunc: Seq[Row] => (Int, Long, Boolean, Row, String) = ...
```

where `Seq[Row]` function argument type and `(Int, Long, Boolean, Row, String)` function result. In another words you create variable of type `Function1[Seq[Row], (Int, Long, Boolean, Row, String)]`

Then goes function body or implementation if you will

```
... = (mem: Seq[Row]) => {
                                //some code
                      (a1,b1,c1,d1,e1) // returning the value
                  }
```

where `mem` is the variable of declared function argument type, which should be the same type or extend the type used in function declaration type. (Function arguments are co-variant. Please, see for more example another good SO post: [Why is Function[-A1,...,+B] not about allowing any supertypes as parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603982/why-is-function-a1-b-not-about-allowing-any-supertypes-as-parameters) )

`=>` statement says that after it goes function body itself.

If you have more `Java` background  or any another imperative language background, this also can be implemented in method manner:

```
def sampleFunc(mem: Seq[Row]): (Int, Long, Boolean, Row, String) =  {
  //some code
  (a1,b1,c1,d1,e1) // returning the value
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

```scala
//<-value name-> <-------------- value type-------------------->   <--------------implementation ----------------------->
//              <-arg type-> <-----result type --------------->   <-function argument->   <----func implementation ---->
val  sampleFunc:  Seq[Row]  => (Int, Long, Boolean, Row, String) = (mem: Seq[Row])      => { /*...*/; (a1,b1,c1,d1,e1) }


//same written differently:
//<-value name-> <-------------- value type------------------------------>   <-------implementation ----------->
val sampleFunc: Funtion1[Seq[Row], Tuple5[Int,Long, Boolean, Row, String]] = {mem => /*...*/; (a1,b1,c1,d1,e1)}
```

- **value name:** nothing special here. Just another `val` in your code.
- **value type:** it is long but pretty straightforward. It is `Function1` type that takes `Seq[Row]` and returns `Tuple5[Int, Long, Boolean, Row, String]`. This is just scala's nicer syntax for it.
- **implementation:** We are creating function that takes `Seq[Row]` using `=>` syntax. Also nothing special here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its easier for you to understand if you desuger the Tuple5 factory method invocations:

```
val sampleFunc: Seq[Row] => Tuple5[Int, Long, Boolean, Row, String] = 
    (mem: Seq[Row]) => Tuple5(a1,b1,c1,d1,e1)
```

and if you go further and replace the `=>` in the type with `Function1` you get:

```
Function1[Seq[Row], Tuple5[Int, Long, Boolean, Row, String]]
```

which means that `sampleFunc` is a function that takes an argument of type `Seq[Row]` and returns a `Tuple5[Int, Long, Boolean, Row, String]`