# @tailrec error "recursive call targetting a supertype"

Tags: scala

Applying @tailrec I'm getting error from scala compiler: "could not optimize @tailrec annotated method get: it contains a recursive call targetting a supertype case _ => tail.get(n-1)". Could someone explain why is that?

```
trait List[T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head: T
  def tail: List[T]
  def get(n: Int): T
}

class Cons[T](val head: T, val tail: List[T]) extends List[T]{
  def isEmpty = false
  @tailrec
  final def get(n: Int) =
    n match {
      case 0 => head
      case _ => tail.get(n-1)
    }
}

class Nil[T] extends List[T]{
  def isEmpty = true
  def head = throw new NoSuchElementException("Nil.head")
  def tail = throw new NoSuchElementException("Nil.tail")
  final def get(n: Int): T = throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException
}

object Main extends App{
  println(new Cons(4, new Cons(7, new Cons(13, new Nil))).get(3))
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to imagine what's happening here and what you're asking the compiler to do. Tail call optimization, roughly, turns the method call into a loop, taking the arguments of the method and turning them into variables that are reassigned at each iteration of the loop.

Here, there are two such “loop variables”: `n` and the list cell itself on which the `get` method is called, which is actually `this` in the method body. The next value for `n` is fine: it's `n - 1` and also an `Int`. The next value for the list cell, which is `tail`, is a problem, however: `this` has type `Cons[T]`, but `tail` only has type `List[T]`.

Thus, there is no way the compiler can turn it into a loop, as there is no guarantee that `tail` is a `Cons[T]` — and sure enough, at the end of the list, it is a `Nil`.

One way to “fix” it would be:

```
case class Cons[T](val head: T, val tail: List[T]) extends List[T] {
  def isEmpty = false
  @tailrec
  final def get(n: Int) =
    n match {
      case 0 => head
      case _ => tail match {
        case c @ Cons(_, _) => c.get(n - 1)
        case nil @ Nil() => nil.get(n - 1)
      }
    }
}
```

(Works if both `Cons` and `Nil` are case classes — but you'll probably want to make `Nil` a `case object` and `List[T]` covariant in `T`.)

Comment: Thank you, I got it! Could you please explain you note regarding "List[T] covariant in T"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/scala-covariance-contravariance-question

Answer (score 2):

In `Cons.get` you call `tail.get` as your tail call. But `tail` is of type `List[T]`, not `Cons[T]`. So that call won't necessarily be handled by `Cons.get`, and Scala can't apply the tail recursion optimisation; the optimisation would turn the method call into a local jump back to the start of `Cons.get`, but that's not necessarily where the call is going.

Answer (score 2):

Ben and Jean-Phillipe Pellet have already explained why the compiler complains. As for how to fix it, there is a straightforward solution: move the implementation of `get` right into `List`:

```
trait List[T] {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head: T
  def tail: List[T]
  @tailrec
  final def get(n: Int): T = {
    n match {
      case 0 => head
      case _ => tail.get(n-1)
    }
  }
}

class Cons[T](val head: T, val tail: List[T]) extends List[T]{
  def isEmpty = false
}

class Nil[T] extends List[T]{
  def isEmpty = true
  def head = throw new NoSuchElementException("Nil.head")
  def tail = throw new NoSuchElementException("Nil.tail")
}
```

Comment: +1 Algebraic Data Types are often much more naturally manipulated with a single function that uses pattern matching, than by spreading the implementation over multiple fragments in each class. As soon as you get forced into something like Jean-Philippe's version where the implementation of `get` in `Cons` is *required* to know what other subclasses of `List` exist, you're often better off moving the whole thing to one place (the base class of the ADT is a natural one).

Comment: I also considered that. But when we come down to Nil, exception "NoSuchElementException: Nil.head" is thrown, and I want it to be IndexOutOfBoundsException, which requires overriding, which in turn will break @tailrec