# Covariance of a passed function argument

Tags: scala, generics, functional-programming

I have made an attempt at implementing a StateMachine in Scala, however I have encountered an issue with the type system that has me rather baffled.  In the code below, I need to have the **guard** function accept an argument of an expected sub-class of StateMachine.  Unfortunately, as the type parameter for **FunctionN** arguments are contravariant, I am not sure how to pull this off.

```
 
class Transition[S, +M <: StateMachine[S]](start: S, end :S, var guard: Option[M => Boolean]) {
// COMPILER ERROR ABOVE LINE : ^^ covariant type M occurs in contravariant position in type => Option[M => Boolean] of method guard ^^
  val startState = start
  val endState = end

  def willFollow(stateMachine: M, withGuard : Boolean) = 
  // COMPILER ERROR ABOVE : ^^ covariant type M occurs in contravariant position in type M of value stateMachine ^^
    if (!withGuard && guard == None) true;
    else (withGuard && guard.get(stateMachine))
}

class EpsilonTransition[S, M <: StateMachine[S]](start: S,end :S) extends Transition[S, M](start, end, None)

class StateMachine[S](transitions: Set[Transition[S, StateMachine[S]]], initialStates: Set[S]) {
    private val stateDrains = transitions.groupBy(_.startState);
    private var activeStates = initialStates

    def act() = {
      var entryStates = Set[S]()
      var exitStates = Set[S]()

      stateDrains.foreach {drain =>  
        val (exitState, transitionsOut) = drain

        // Follow non-epsilon transitions
        transitionsOut.filter(_.willFollow(this, true)).foreach {transition =>
          exitStates += transition.startState
          entryStates += transition.endState
        }
      }

      // For all exit states we map the state to a set of transitions, and all sets are "flattened" into one big set of transitions
      // which will then filter by those which do not have a guard (epsilon transitions). The resulting filtered list of transitions
      // all contain endStates that we will map to. All of those end states are appended to the current set of entry states.
      entryStates = entryStates ++ (exitStates.flatMap(stateDrains(_)).filter(_.willFollow(this, false)).map(_.endState))

      // Exclude only exit states which we have not re-entered 
      // and then include newly entered states
      activeStates = ((activeStates -- (exitStates -- entryStates)) ++ entryStates) 
    }

    override def toString = activeStates.toString
}

object HvacState extends Enumeration {
     type HvacState = Value
     val aircon, heater, fan = Value
}
import HvacState._

object HvacTransitions {
    val autoFan = new EpsilonTransition[HvacState, HVac](aircon, fan)
    val turnOffAc = new Transition[HvacState, HVac](aircon, fan, Some(_.temperature  75))
    val HeaterToFan = new Transition[HvacState,HVac](heater, fan, Some(_.temperature > 50))
}
import HvacTransitions._

class HVac extends StateMachine[HvacState](Set(autoFan, turnOffAc, AcToHeater, HeaterToAc, HeaterToFan), Set(heater)) {
  var temperature = 40
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for trait Transition to be declared with a +M parameter?

Comment: Why do you want `M` covariant? Just curious.

Comment: M is covariant (+M) because if I don't mark it as such than the third line to the end of the code snipplet where class HVac extends StateMachine[HVacState] ... will show an error for all of the transitions that I pass to the StateMachine constructor.  Each error states that while we have a Transition of parameter HVac, a transition of StateMachine[HVacState] is expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your transitions works only for a certain type of states, but also for a certain type of state machine, so the two type parameters `S` and `M`. For instance, at the end, you have transitions may depend on the temperature, which is a property of the StateMachine and not of just the State.

Somehow, a state machine should have only transitions that are compatible with it. A transition that needs access to temperature should not be allowed on a state machine without a temperature. The type system will enforce that. However, your code makes no provision for that.

Instead you have class StateMachine getting a Set of Transition[S, StateMachine[S]]. This works, but the consequence is that a StateMachine accepts only "standard" transitions, that will not require anything special from the machine. You can define transitions requiring special machines (with temperature) but there is nothing for a machine to accepts those special transitions even when they would be compatible with it.

Then comes your Hvac machine, which has temperature. You try to give pass it special transitions, transitions that can operate only on Hvac  machine (accessing the temperature).  But the ancestor constructor is written to accept standard transitions only. The compiler rejects that. It suggest that if Transition was covariant in M, it would be ok. This is true, except that Transition cannot be covariant in M. It takes a machine as an input. A covariant transition would mean that if it can operate on a very special machine, it must also be able to operate also on a less special machine. Not what you want.

What you need to do is have class StandardMachine accepts special transitions, which it now rejects, but of course only transitions that are compatible with the machine (if you don't give this guarantee, the compiler will reject the code).
Probably the easier way to do that is to put the type M in the machine too, so that you can express the constraint properly.

Here is a possible way. First we add a type parameter to StateMachine

```
class StateMachine[S, M](
```

we need to add the M parameter everywhere StateMachine is referenced, for instance
`class Transition[S, M <: StateMachine[S, M]]`, or `class Hvac extends StateMachine[HvacState, Hvac]`

Of course, the constructor parameters become

```
class StateMachine[S,M](transitions: Set[Transition[S, M]]], ...
```

Here we states that the machine is ok for its transitions. Except that we did not. It still does not compile, each time we pass `this`, the machine to a transition, for instance:

```
transitionsOut.filter(_.willFollow(this, true)).foreach {transition =>
                                   ^^
type mismatch;  found   : StateMachine.this.type (with underlying type StateMachine[S,M])  required: M
```

Well, we introduced type M, but we are not passing some M to the machine, we are passing `this`. This is a StateMachine[S, M], it needs not be an M. We certainly intend M to be the type of the machine, but this needs not be the case. We hate to state that a StateMachine[S, M] must be an M. We do that with a self type :

```
class StateMachine[S, M](
   transitions: Set[Transition[S, M]], 
   initialStates: Set[S]) { this: M => 
 // body of the class
```

}

this: M => states that every instance of the class must be an instance of the generic parameter M. We force this to be an M, so the error disappears.

Then the constraint `M <: StateMachine[S, M`] in `Transition` comes in the way, we don't need it and we simply remove it : `Transition[S, M]`. Alternatively, we can put the same constraint on StateMachine.

This make full use of the type system with the problem as it was stated, but it might be simpler to isolate the machine state, that is, instead of having the self `type this: M =>`,  have some `def machineState: M`, and pass that to the guard instead of `this`. In this case, `Hvac` would be a `StateMachine[HvacState, Double]` (or some more explicit encapsulation of the temperature than Double),

---

Summary  of my changes :

- Transition: Removing the constraint on M, removing covariance :

  class Transition[S, M](...
- EpsilonTransition : removing the constraint on M

  class EpsilonTransition[S, M]
- `StateMachine` : Add type parameter `M`, use `M` as parameter for the transitions, and set `M` as self type :

  class StateMachine[S, M](transitions: Set[Transition[S, M]], initialStates: Set[S]) { this: M =>
- `turnOffAcc` : an operator is missing in the code you copied, added `<`
- `HVac` : added itself as second generic parameter : `class HVac extends StateMachine[HvacState]`. Also, some of the transitions, `AcToHeater` and `HeaterToAc` do not appear in the code you copied, so I just removed them.

Comment: I was I actually expecting your suggestions to work but I am now seeing errors on only one line (where class HVac extends StateMachine[HvacState, HVac](Set(autoFan, turnOffAc, AcToHeater, HeaterToAc, HeaterToFan), Set(heater))) ... each of the transitions are being pointed out by the compiler as not having the correct type ... stating the transitions have param of HVac where StateMachine is expected.  This would seem to indicate I need covariance.  But, +M or not: same errors.

Comment: Compiles fine for me. I added a list of the changes I made to your code.

Comment: First off, please forgive my botched copy-paste job, SO must have dropped the aforementioned elements during the paste, next time I'll check more carefully.

Comment: All my compiler errors are now cleared!  The piece I was missing was passing the M parameter from StateMachine through to the Transition (hence resulting in a type mis-alignment between both classes).  Once the errors were cleared, I also re-introduced the type bounds on M for Transition, EpsilonTransition, and StateMachine (just to guarantee users of each class don't try to pass non StateMachine sub-classes to either of these classes.  For this reason, I'm effectively forcing StateMachine context to reside within subclasses .. so I will mark StateMachine as an abstract class.

Comment: Finally, I wanted to thank you for awesome break-down of all the parts I had wrong and detailed explanations for each element.  As an aside: this StateMachine implementation is a port from Java, and turned out to be more succinct than the original version than I would have ever imagined possible.  Furthermore, It's a totally elegant implementation.  This proved to be a great exercise in learning the Scala Type system, and If I could vote up your answer 20 times I would :-)  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this (it compiles for me):

```
class Transition[S, M <: StateMachine[S]](start: S, end: S, var guard: Option[M => Boolean]) {
  val startState = start
  val endState = end

  def willFollow[MM <: M](stateMachine: MM, withGuard: Boolean) =
    if (!withGuard && guard == None) true
    else (withGuard && guard.get(stateMachine))
}
```

Basically, `Option[M => Boolean]` will take any function that takes an M or greater and goes to boolean. For instance, `Any => Boolean` would work. This is contravariant. However, your `willFollow` method needs to take anything less than M since it's applying to a function of at least type M. Here's a better explanation, since you're probably looking for one: [Why doesn't the example compile, aka how does (co-, contra-, and in-) variance work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/scala-covariance-contravariance-question?rq=1)

Comment: Interesting thought.  I actually also asked another StackOverflow regular and he suggested that I keep +M in Transition but instead of MM <: M ... I use MM >: M.  Because if Transition isn't covariant in M, the line of code where HVac extends StateMachine fails to compile.  So, it seems that Transition *has to be* covariant in M.  But, with MM >: M ... guard.get(stateMachine) fails to compile.  Something is fundamentally wrong with what I am trying to do, which is frustrating since this certainly seems like a sensible design.

Comment: Yeah, the more I look at what you're trying to do I don't think this will work. If you start replacing M's with StateMachine[S] you might start to see what I mean. Frustrating.

Comment: Indeed, especially considering what I am trying to do doesn't seem particularly complex, yet I'm already running into limitations with the type system.

Comment: It is rather the type system telling you that your code does not state the relations between machine and transitions properly ;-)