# Function returning the most specific type

Tags: scala, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I would like to have higher-order-function `Function[K=>V, K=>V]` which takes a function `K=>V` and returns the type of the given function. For example I would like to have the following behaviour:

```
  class Foo[K, V]() {
    def apply[K1 <: K, V1 <: V](f: K1 => V1) = f
  }

  // dummy class hierachy
  class A
  class B extends A
  class C extends B

    // a function f: B=>B
  def f(some: B): B = some

  // the desired result
  val result1: B => B = new Foo[A, A]()(f)
```

The apply method of `Foo` takes a `B=>B` and returns a `B=>B`. The type-parameters `K` and `V` keep track of the "highest" type `Foo` can take as an argument. Now, I would like `Foo` to extend Function like

```
  class Bar[K, V] extends Function[K=>V, K=>V]() {
    def apply(f: K => V) = f
  }

  val result2: B => B = new Bar[A, A]()(f)
```

however this does obviously not work. Is there a way to make this work?
Thanks

**Edit**

```
  class Fuzz[K, V, K1 <: K, V1 <: V] extends Function[K1=>V1, K1=>V1] {
    def apply(f: K1 => V1) = f
  }

  val result3: B => B = new Fuzz[A, A, B, B]()(f)
```

Also works, however I don't wanna carry the two additional type-parameters

Comment: This may be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/663254/1019358

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot and should not work, because `A => A` is not a subtype of `B => B` (and not a supertype either). The reason for that is that Function1 is covariant in its argument type and contravariant in its result type. Thus for `A => A` to be a subtype of `B => B`, `A` would have to be a subtype *as well as* a supertype of `B`. That is only the case if `A` and `B` are in fact the same type. See the [tour of Scala for a more in depth explanation of variance](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/129).