# Error with definition covariant and contravariant types

Tags: scala

I have code:

```
class A {
    override def toString = "object class A"
}

class B extends A {
    override def toString = "object class B"
}

class Cell[+T](init: T) {
    private[this] var current: T = init
    def get: T = current
    def set(x: T) { current = x }
}

val cB = new Cell[B](new B)
println(cB.get)
val cA: Cell[A] = cB
println(cA.get)
```

but I have error in line: `def set(x: T) { current = x }`

> error: covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type T of
>   value x
>           def set(x: T) { current = x }

Explain, please

Comment: In addition to the insightful answers, why do you need the explicit private reference and getter/setter? Scala does this for you: `class Cell[+T](val t: T) {...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contravariant positions for a type are (among others) any positions that allow you to pass an instance of that type to a method. So all method parameter types are in contravariant positions. Since you declared T as covariant ( `+T`), the compiler won't allow this. Your only options are:

- make `T` invariant
- modify the set method such that it returns a new instance of `Cell` and `Cell` thus becomes immutable.
- remove the set method, also making `Cell` immutable

If the compiler allowed you to have a set method as you implemented it, that would make the type system unsafe, since it would allow you to write:

```
val cs:Cell[String] = new Cell("")
val ca:Cell[Any] = cs
ca.set(5)
val s:String = cs.get //boom
```

Comment: Should be `ca.set(5)` instead of `cs.set(5)`

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that you cannot have a mutable container which is covariant.  Assuming this compiled, then in your example, the last two lines could read:

```
val cA: Call[A] = cB
cA.set(new A)
```

The first line would be allowed, because a `Cell[B]` *is* a `Cell[A]` due to the use of `+T`.  And then the second line is allowed too - because of course you can set a `Cell[A]` to hold an `A`.

But now, `cB.get` returns an instance of `A`, not a `B`!  This doesn't make any sense, and there is no way to resolve this contradiction while still allowing covariance in Cell's type parameter.

---

For a longer, more formal/comprehensive answer, see this question: [Scala covariance/contravariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/scala-covariance-contravariance-question)