# scala predicate basic

Tags: scala

I'm very new to scala so you may forgive me this basic newbie question. I have following code snippet.

```
type Pred[A, B] = (A, B) => Int;
def abs[A, B](p: (A, B) => Int): (A, B) => Int =
  (a, b) => if (p(a, b) < 0) -(p(a, b)) else (p(a, b));
def multiply(a: Int, b: Int): Int =
  a * b;
def subtract(a: Int, b: Int): Int =
  a - b;

val absMultiply = abs(multiply);
val absSubstract = abs(subtract);

println("abs(10 * 10) = " + absMultiply.apply(10, 10));
println("abs(10 - 100) = " + absSubstract.apply(10, 100));
```

So as I've understand it correctly it should be possible to replace (A,B) => Int with Pred[A, B].

```
def abs[A, B](p: Pred[A, B]): Pred[A, B] =
  (a, b) => if (p(a, b) < 0) -(p(a, b)) else (p(a, b));
```

But then I get an compiler exception

```
type mismatch;  found   : (Int, Int) => Int  required: (A, B) => Int    
type mismatch;  found   : (Int, Int) => Int  required: (A, B) => Int
```

Have I misunderstood here something wrong?

Thank you very much for your help.

Cyrill

Comment: What version are you using? With 2.9.2 I am not seeing any issue nor anything that seems syntactically incorrect.

Comment: FWIW, and irrespective of your question, the word "Predicate" usually refers to a Boolean valued function (usually of one argument), rather than in Integer valued one.  You might consider something like "BinOp" rather than "Pred" as a name, if you don't want to confuse people.

Comment: @RyanO'Neill .. I'm using 2.10.0

Comment: @Dave thank you for clarification.. so many terms I never heard of before ;-).. I'm slowly learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you declare A and B as contravariant types:

```
type Pred[-A, -B] = (A, B) => Int
```

This is necessary because for `multiply` and `subtract` functions to be considered subtypes of Pred[A, B], their arguments must be supertypes of A and B. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/674090/196068) answer for an excellent explanation on the subject.