# How to understand the two sentences about "Covariance" and "Contravariance"?

Tags: scala, type-systems

I'm reading the first section of "Scala in depth", there are two sentences in the first section about "covariance" and "contrvariance":

> Covariance (+T or ? extends T) is when a type can be coerced down the inheritance hierarchy.
>
> Contravariance(-T or ? super T) is when a type can be coerced up the inheritance hierarchy.

I have read some documents about "Covariance" and "Contravariance", but I can't understand the word "coerced down" and "coerced up" here in this context.

Comment: The first is called 'covariance' (not 'convariance'), so I have edited this

Comment: @0__ Thank you, that's a hard word :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala covariance / contravariance question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/scala-covariance-contravariance-question)

Comment: @dhg I think the question is perhaps not "what is covariance/contravariance?" but rather "what has coercion got to do with it (and which type is being coerced, etc)?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[TOP / ABSTRACT]

Thing
  ↓
Animal
  ↓
Human
  ↓
Programmer
  ↓
Scala Dev

[BOTTOM / SPECIFIC]
```

**Covariance:** Accept T or lower.

I asked for a `[+Human]`, I will accept any of these: `[Human, Programmer, Scala Dev]`.

**Contravariance:** Accept T or higher.

I asked for a `[-Human]`, I will accept any of these: `[Thing, Animal, Human]`.

**Inariance:** Accept T and only T.

**Coercion.**

Coercing a type up/down the type hierarchy means checking that a type's super/sub type passes type constraints. For example, a covariant function needs a `Human` but we've only got a `Programmer`, that's ok, the compiler can *coerce* the `Programmer` into `Human` to satisfy typing constraints.

Comment: Great answer. The only question is in the case of "For example, a covariant function needs a Human but we've only got a Programmer, that's ok, the compiler can coerce the Programmer into Human to satisfy typing constraints.", we should call it "coerce up" or "coerce down"?

Comment: Coercing a Programmer into a Human would be "coercing up". Hey I just realised that's the opposite of what the excerpt you pasted says! Hmmm, I'd say the author made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In this case coerced means the compiler can treat the type as a type further up/down the inheritance hierarchy.

Think of it as upcasting or downcasting except the compiler is doing it automatically, so it is not a cast (which could suggest that explicit code was required to perform it).

Answer (score 1):

This response is taken from lectures given by Martin Odersky (the creator of Scala) on Coursera. We note:

```
S<:T means: S is a subtype of T, and
S>:T means: S is a supertype of T, or T is a subtype of S.
```

Say `C[T]` is a parameterized type and A, B are types such that `A<:B`.
In general there is three possible relationships between `C[A]` and `C[B]`:

```
C[A]<:C[B] ---------> C is covariant
C[A]>:C[B] ---------> C is contravariant
neither C[A] nor C[B] is a subtype of the other ---------> C is nonvariant
```

Scala lets you declare the variance of a type by annotating the type parameter:

```
class C[+A] { ... }  ---------> C is covariant
class C[-A] { ... } ----------> C is contravariant
class C[A]  { ... } ----------> C is nonvariant
```

Hope this might help!