# Understanding List[+A] for Covariance

Tags: scala

Looking at the source for [List.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala?source=c#L83):

```
sealed abstract class List[+A] extends ... 

  ...

  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def head: A
  def tail: List[A]
```

`List[+A]` is covariant based on the `+A`. Does this mean that, it's possible to create a `List[T]` where T can be the type itself, or any of its sub-classes?

example:

```
scala> trait Kid
defined trait Kid

scala> case class Boy(name: String) extends Kid
defined class Boy

scala> case class Girl(name: String) extends Kid
defined class Girl

scala> val list: List[Kid] = List(Boy("kevin"), Girl("sally"))
list: List[Kid] = List(Boy(kevin), Girl(sally))
```

Observe that `head` and `tail`'s types are `A` and `List[A]`, respectively. Once we've defined `List[+A]`, then `head` and `tail`'s `A` is also covariant?

I've read this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/scala-covariance-contravariance-question) 3 or 4 times, but I don't understand yet.

Comment: The example code doesn't depend on `List` covariance at all. Could you expand your question/example so that it is clearer?

Comment: Basically I was confused on variance and asked a question to provoke an answer on the topic. Vladimir helped me out a lot with his answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your example does not relate to variance. Moreover, head and tail have nothing to do with variance too.

```
scala> val list: List[Kid] = List(Boy("kevin"), Girl("sally"))
list: List[Kid] = List(Boy(kevin), Girl(sally))
```

This would work even if `List` weren't covariant, because Scala will automatically deduce common supertype of `Boy` and `Girl`, that is, `Kid`, and type of the expression on the right side will be `List[Kid]`, exactly what you require on the left side.

The following, however, *doesn't* work because `java.util.List` is not covariant (it is invariant since it is Java type):

```
scala> import java.util.{List => JList, Arrays}
import java.util.{List=>JList, Arrays}

scala> trait Kid
defined trait Kid

scala> case class Boy(name: String) extends Kid
defined class Boy

scala> val list1 = Arrays.asList(Boy("kevin"), Boy("bob"))
list1: java.util.List[Boy] = [Boy(kevin), Boy(bob)]

scala> val list2: JList[Kid] = list1
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.List[Boy]
 required: java.util.List[Kid]
Note: Boy <: Kid, but Java-defined trait List is invariant in type E.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Kid`. (SLS 3.2.10)
       val list2: JList[Kid] = list1
                               ^
```

`Arrays.asList` method has signature like this:

```
def asList[T](args: T*): java.util.List[T]
```

As `java.util.List[T]` is invariant, it is impossible to assign `JList[Boy]` (`list1`) to `JList[Kid]` (`list2`). And there is a reason: if you could, then because `JList` is mutable, you could also add anything extending `Kid` (not only `Boy`) into the same list, breaking type safety.

On the other hand, `scala.List` *will* work in exactly the same situation:

```
scala> val list1 = List(Boy("kevin"), Boy("bob"))
list1: List[Boy] = List(Boy(kevin), Boy(bob))

scala> val list2: List[Kid] = list1
list2: List[Kid] = List(Boy(kevin), Boy(bob))
```

That is because `scala.List` is covariant in its type parameter. Note that covariant `List` type works as if `List[Boy]` were subtype of `List[Kid]`, very similar to the case when you can assign everything to a variable of type `Any` because every other type is a subtype of `Any`. This is very helpful analogy.

Contravariance works in a very similar way, but in other direction. Consider this trait:

```
trait Predicate[-T] {
  def apply(obj: T): Boolean
}

object Predicate {
  // convenience method to convert functions to predicates
  def apply[T](f: (T) => Boolean) = new Predicate[T] {
    def apply(obj: T) = f(obj)
  }
}
```

Note the `-` before `T` parameter: it is a contravariance annotation, that is, `Predicate[T]` is defined to be contravariant in its only type parameter.

Recall that for covariant list `List[Boy]` was a subtype of `List[Kid]`. Well, for contravariant predicate it works in the opposite way: `Predicate[Kid]` is a subtype of `Predicate[Boy]`, so you can assign a value of type `Predicate[Kid]` to a variable of type `Predicate[Boy]`:

```
scala> val pred1: Predicate[Kid] = Predicate { kid => kid.hashCode % 2 == 0 }
pred1: Predicate[Kid] = Predicate$$anon$1@3bccdcdd

scala> val pred2: Predicate[Boy] = pred1
pred2: Predicate[Boy] = Predicate$$anon$1@3bccdcdd
```

If `Predicate[T]` weren't contravariant, we wouldn't be able to assign `pred1` to `pred2`, though it is completely legitimate and safe: obviously, predicates defined on supertypes can easily work on subtypes.

---

In short, variance affects type compatibility between parameterized types. `List` is covariant, so you can assign a value of type `List[Boy]` to a variable of type `List[Kid]` (in fact, for any `T` extending `S`, you can assign a value of type `List[T]` to a variable of type `List[S]`).

On the other hand, because, `Predicate` is contravariant, you can assign `Predicate[Kid]` to `Predicate[Boy]` (that is, for any `T` extending `S`, you can assign a value of type `Predicate[S]` to a variable of type `Predicate[T]`).

If a type is invariant in its type parameter, neither of the above can be done (as is demonstrated by `JList`).

Note the correspondence between parameterized types and their parameters:

```
T <: S   ===>   List     [T] <: List     [S]  (covariance)
T <: S   ===>   Predicate[S] <: Predicate[T]  (contravariance)
```

This is the reason why the first effect is called *co*variance (`T <: S` on the left, and
`..T.. <: ..S..` on the right), and the second is *contra*variance (`T <: S` on the left, but `..S.. <: ..T..` on the right).

Whether to make your own parameterized types covariant or contravariant or invariant depends on your class responsibilities. If it may only *return* values of generic type, then it makes sense to use covariance. `List[T]`, for example, only contains methods which return `T`, never accept `T` as a parameter, so it is safe to make it covariant in order to increase expressiveness. Such parameterized types can be called *producers*.

If your class only *accepts* values of the generic type as a parameter, not returns them (exactly like `Predicate` above which has single method `def apply(obj: T): Boolean`), then you can safely make it contravariant. Such parameterized types can be called *consumers*

If your class both accepts and returns values of the generic type, i.e. it is both a producer and a consumer, then you have no choice but to leave the class invariant in this generic type parameter.

This idiom is usually called "PECS" ("Producer `extends`, Consumer `super`") because variance annotations are written `extends` and `super` in Java.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer.  Could you please give me 1 more example on predicate?  I'm still not understanding contravariance in argument and covariance in return type.

Comment: @KevinMeredith, I have updated the answer with examples of contravariance.

Comment: As I understand - you pointed out `List[Kid]` accepting a `Boy` type: `List[Kid](Boy("kevin"), ...)` has nothing to do with variance. It's simply that a sub-type can be used where a parent type is defined - basic OO. So, what I'm still confused about is this: for `List[A]`, that means that the class List has a co-variant type A. Co-variant means that A or its sub-type can be used. But, couldn't we already use A's sub-type given the OO nature of Scala? It seems to me that `variance` changes which types and sub-types can be used.

Comment: @KevinMeredith, "But, couldn't we already use A's sub-type given the OO nature of Scala?". Again, it has nothing to do with `List[A]` and variance. Using `A` on its own and as a type parameter is a absolutely different matter. When you put `A` as a parameter to another type `List`, you obtain completely new type `List[A]` which itself is *atomic*. `List[A]` and `List[B]` are different types in general. Variance allows to establish subtype relationship between them if only `A` and `B` are already in this relationship, that's all.