# why the first type parameter is defined as contravariant in Function1[-A, +B]?

Tags: scala

all
  after reading [Scala covariance / contravariance question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/674090/1054800) and its answer provided by Daniel Spiewak,and Section 19.3-19.7 of book "Programming in Scala", I have another confusion about the definion of Function1[-A, +B]: why its first type parameter is contravariant?  I got one reason,  it is that this type parameter guarantees that the subtypes always appear earlier than supertypes when there are multiple cases, at the same time, subtype "is a" supertype. for example:

```
 class A
 class B extends A
 class C extends B
 scala> val withDefault: A => B = {
 | case x:B => new B
 | case x:A => new B }
 withDefault: A => B = <function1>
```

here, (1) `case x:B` is earlier than `case x:A` , (2) Function1[A,B] <: Function1[B,B]
  and there must be other reasons? any message will be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Contravariance has nothing to do with pattern matching. Here's why function types are contravariant on their argument types. Consider this function:

```
def doHigherOrder(handleAnyAnimal: Animal => T,
                  anyAnimal:       Animal     ): T = {
  // ...foo...
  handleAnyAnimal(anyAnimal)
  // ...bar...
}
```

If functions were covariant not contravariant, then a function `Duck => T` would also be a subtype of `Animal => T` and you could do `doHigherOrder(handleAnyDuck)`. This would be an error because then, inside `doHigherOrder`, the `handleAnyAnimal(anyAnimal)` expression would (at runtime/evaluation) boil down to `handleAnyDuck(anyAnimal)`, which is obviously not right because a function that can handle any `Duck` probably can't handle any `Animal`:

```
def doHigherOrder(handleAnyDuck: Duck => T,
                  anyAnimal:     Animal   ): T = {
  // ...foo...
  handleAnyDuck(anyAnimal)  // <-- ERROR
  // ...bar...
}
```

Moreover, assuming `Creature >: Animal`, a function `handleAnyCreature: Creature => T` is indeed also a subtype of `Animal => T`, because it is OK to pass `anyAnimal` into something that can accept `anyCreature`.

That's why contravariance is intuitively inevitable with argument types.

---

However, return values are covariant because they have exactly the same semantics as just values:

```
val animal = getDuck()    // ok
val duck   = getAnimal()  // <-- ERROR
```

compare with

```
val x = handleDuck(animal)  // <-- ERROR
val y = handleAnimal(duck)  // ok
```

Figuratively, you assign *to* function arguments, but *from* their return values. It becomes more obvious with named arguments:

```
val x = handle(duck   = animal) // <-- ERROR
val y = handle(animal = duck  ) // ok
```