# What is the variance of `K >: T` and `K <: T` if `T` is covariant or contravariant?

Tags: scala, covariance, contravariance, type-systems, variance

If `T` is covariant or contravariant, can I determine the variance of:

```
K >: T
```

or

```
K <: T
```

I ask this because I see in the book "programming in scala", it says, in the code:

```
trait Cat[T] {
   def meow[K]
}
```

The position of `K` is negative, it must be contravariant(Let's assume it's not a nonvariant type).

Since we can't just declare covariance or contravariance just with a single type `K`, we have to use upper bound or lower bound, so the `K` may be:

```
K >: T
```

or

```
K <: T
```

But how can I determine new type is covariant or contravariant?

Comment: do you mean "contravariant/covariant" instead of "contravariance/covariance"?

Comment: Thank you, sorry for my bad English

Comment: I don't see a relation between `K` and `T` in `trait Cat[T]{ def meow[K] }` so it doesn't seem like there needs to be a relationship.

Comment: `K` is just indicating the position in that piece of code, actually, it may be `K >: T` or `K <: T`

Comment: Unless `K` itself is a type parameter of `Cat`, I don't see how `Cat` can have any variance relationship with `K`... unless I'm mistaken. Also, I think it's a misnomer to say that "a type is covariant/contravariant"... because a type can only be *variant with respect to one or more of its type parameters.

Answer (score 4):

As I already noted in a comment, type variance can only be talked of in relation to a type parameter. A type itself isn't covariant or contravariant or invariant. Since `K` does not appear in the type parameter list of `Cat`, `Cat` has no variance in relation to `K`. Consider:

```
trait Cat[T] {
  def meow[K]
}

class SiameseCat[T] extends Cat[T] {
  def meow[K] = println("loud meow")
}

class Foo
class Bar extends Foo
class Baz extends Bar

val barSiamese = new SiameseCat[Bar]

// COMPILATION ERROR: personality.analysis.demo.Bar <: personality.analysis.demo.Foo, but class SiameseCat is invariant in type T
val fooSiamese: SiameseCat[Foo] = barSiamese
// SAME
val bazSiamese: SiameseCat[Baz] = barSiamese

// NO ERROR
barSiamese.meow[Foo]
barSiamese.meow[Bar]
barSiamese.meow[Baz]
barSiamese.meow[Int]
barSiamese.meow[Unit]
```

Arguably, in more lax speech, you can say a type is *variant if it's obviously a container type and takes just one type parameter, such as `List[T]`; i.e. one can say `List` is covariant, but this actually expands to *"`List[T]` is covariant with respect to `T`"*.

However, if `K` did in fact appear in the type parameter list of `Cat`, it would make it possible to declare `Cat` as covariant with respect to `K` by prepending a `+` to `K`: `Cat[T, +K]`, which will be allowed by the compiler because `K` only appears in variance-neutral positions in the body of `Cat`:

```
def meow[K]  // <-- meow doesn't take any parameters and returns `Unit`, so `K` is irrelevant with respect to variance
```

if, however, you were returning `K` from `meow`, you'd only be able to mark `Cat` as invariant or covariant with respect to `K`:

```
def meow: K  // contravariance made impossible
```

conversely, this:

```
def meow(x: K)  // covariance made impossible
```

would force you to either go with `Cat[T, -K]` (contravariant) or just `Cat[T, K]` (invariant).

For the reason why, either google, or see a recent answer of mine @ [why the first type parameter is defined as contravariant in Function1[-A, +B]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308555/why-the-first-type-parameter-is-defined-as-contravariant-in-function1-a-b/23310024#23310024)

Answer (score 1):

The type parameters of *methods* such as `K` in `def meow[K]` can't be co- or contravariant. The notion can only apply to type parameters of types.

> Since we can't just declare covariance or contravariance just with a single type K, we have to use upper bound or lower bound

This also doesn't make sense. We can declare that `MyClass` is covariant in `K` like this:

```
class MyClass[+K]
```

This is completely unrelated to lower/upper bounds: you can have a variant type parameter with or without a bound.

Answer (score 0):

Two type of variance for:

```
class X1
class X2 extends X1
class X3 extends X2
```

1) Declaration-site variance:

```
// covariant type-constructor:
class Cat[+T]

var cat : Cat[X2] = new Cat[X2]
var cat = new Cat[X3]
// cat = new Cat[X1] // not compiled
```

2) Using-site variance (by upper or lower bound limitation):

```
//covariant variable for invariant type constructor:
class Cat[T]

var cat : Cat[_ <: X2] = new Cat[X2]
cat = new Cat[X3]
// cat = new Cat[X1] // not compiled
```

Decalration-site variance used in type-constructor(container) declaration and using-site variance commonly used in method or variavle declararion.

Comment: What is the `Foo` in `Cat[_ <: Foo]`?

Comment: My apologies. Bug fixed