# scala.Any in the Scala Class Hierarchy

Tags: scala

In Scala, many types extend Any. [Click here](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/71%3Fsize=_original.html#) for a diagram of the Scala Class Hierarchy.

For instance, Double and Tuple both extend Any and the code below works as expected:

```
def foo(x: Any) { println(x.toString) }
foo(3.0) // prints: 3.0
foo((2,3)) //prints: (2,3)
```

However, I don't understand why the following doesn't work, since it follows all the logic above:

```
def bar(fn: Any => String) { println(fn.toString) }

def dub(d: Double): String = "dub"
def tup(tup: (Int, Int)): String = "tup"

bar(dub) // ERROR
bar(tup) // ERROR
```

Calling bar(dub) and bar(tup) both result in a type mismatch error. For bar(dub) the compiler says:

```
error: type mismatch;
found: Double => String
required: Any => String
```

Can someone explain to me why there is a type mismatch in the second case even though Any is a supertype?

Answer (score 8):

Because `Double => String` is not a subtype of `Any => String`.

Think of it this way: `bar` requires an argument that is a function that can turn **anything** into a string.  You are giving it a function that can turn a **double** into a string, but it's not able to turn anything *else* into a string.  Thus, it's not what `bar` is looking for.

Note that the reverse would hold: a `Double => String` argument would be able to accept an `Any => String` function.

The reason for this is that `Function1` is defined as `Function1[-T1, +R]`, and the `-T1` means that the first type parameter is *contravariant* (the second is *covariant*).  You can read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/scala-covariance-contravariance-question).