# Scala covariance and lower bound i dont get it

Tags: scala, covariance, generic-variance

I am currently learning scala and i am confused about the variance annotations especially the **covariance** and **contravariance**.

So i did some research an came upon following example

```
 class Box[+T] {

    def put[U >: T](x: U): List[U] = {
      List(x)
    }

  }

  class Animal {

  }

  class Cat extends Animal {

  }

  class Dog extends Animal {

  }

  var sb: Box[Animal] = new Box[Cat];
```

So this says class Box is covariant in T whiche means Box[Cat] is a subclass of Box[Animal] since Cat is a subclass of Animal. Sofar i understand this. But when it comes to method parameters my understanding ends. The spec says methods parameters can not be covariant so we have to use this lower bound annotation.

Lets look at the method definiton

```
 def put[U >: T](x: U): List[U] = {
   List(x)
 }
```

> So [U >: T] says that U must be a superclass of T

Trying following code

```
  var sb: Box[Animal] = new Box[Cat];
  sb.put(new Cat);
```

Works as expected but this drives me nuts

```
  var sb: Box[Animal] = new Box[Cat];
  sb.put(1);
```

It logically makes no sense to me to put an **INT** into a Box of Animals alltough its correct since **INT** will be resolved to **Any** which is a superclass of **Animal**.

**So my question is**

How do i have to adapt the code that the `put method` accepts only subtypes of
animal? I can not use the upper bound annotation

```
class Box[+T] {

    def put[U <: T](x: U): List[U] = {
      List(x)
    }

  }
```

since i get this well known error

> covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add both a lower and an upper bound:

```
class Box[+T] { def put[U >: T <: Animal](x: U): List[U] = List(x) }
```

But this is not what you want, since you wire the definition of `Box` to `Animal` and logically there is no reason to add such an upper bound.

You say:

> It logically makes no sense to me to put an INT into a Box of Animals alltough its correct since INT will be resolved to Any which is a superclass of Animal.

You don't put an `Int` into a `Box[Animal]`, the existing box is immutable (and it is not possible to make it mutable, since the definition of covariance doesn't allow it). Instead you get a box (or in case of your `put` method) of a new type. If your goal is to get only a `List[Anmial]`, then you just have to specify that:

```
scala> class Box[+T] { def put[U >: T](x: U): List[U] = List(x) }
defined class Box

scala> var b: Box[Animal] = new Box[Cat]
b: Box[Animal] = Box@23041911

scala> val xs: List[Animal] = b put new Dog
xs: List[Animal] = List(Dog@f8d6ec4)

scala> val xs: List[Animal] = b put 1
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: Animal
       val xs: List[Animal] = b put 1
                                    ^

scala> val xs = b put 1 // this will result in a List[Any]
xs: List[Any] = List(1)
```

There is no need to complicate the definition of the `put` method.

For a more in depth explanation about why co- and contravariance is needed see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/why-doesnt-the-example-compile-aka-how-does-co-contra-and-in-variance-w).

Comment: Ok makes sense but what does the term the existing box is immutable mean ? Why is it immutable ?

Comment: Because the definition of covariance ensures immutability (covariance means read only, whereas contravariance means write only), see the linked question.