# scala type with plus sign in front

Tags: scala

```
sealed trait List[+A] // `List` data type, parameterized on a type, `A`
case object Nil extends List[Nothing] // A `List` data constructor representing the empty list
/* Another data constructor, representing nonempty lists. Note that `tail` is another `List[A]`,
which may be `Nil` or another `Cons`.
 */
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
```

My question is what is the "+" in front of A?
Why in here "List[A]" the plus is ignored?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/why-doesnt-the-example-compile-aka-how-does-co-contra-and-in-variance-w

Comment: I read that well-written post, linked by `Mr. V.`, a few times before understanding it. So don't be discouraged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A plus or minus sign in front of a type constructor argument means that values of that type appear in covariant (`+`) or contravariant (`-`) position. A covariant position means the type only ever occurs as "output" or return type, as is the case with `List`. Then a `List[A]` is a subtype of a `List[B]` if `A <: B`, if `A` is a sub-type of `B`:

```
trait Animal { def food: String }
case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal { def food = "all" }

def test(xs: List[Animal]) = xs.map(_.food)

test(List(Dog("Jussi")))
```

Here you can pass a `List[Dog]` for a `List[Animal]` because `List[Dog] <: List[Animal]`.

Contravariance is the opposite - the type only occurs as input. For example `Function1[A, Out] <: Function1[B, Out]` if `A >: B`, if `A` is a super-type of `B`.

```
def test(fun: Dog => String): String = fun(Dog("Jussi"))

test { x: Animal => x.food }
```

Here you can pass a `Animal => String` for a `Dog => String` because the former is sub-type of the latter.

---

The variance annotation `+` or `-` only ever occurs in the definition of the type, so in the definition of `List[+A]`, not anywhere else where `List` is used, e.g. as type ascription or in the `extends` clause, because the variance cannot change once it's defined. This is called definition-site variance.

---

Because `Nothing` is the *bottom* type in Scala, a type that is the sub-type of any other type, we can thus have the convenient `object Nil extends List[Nothing]`, and thereby `Nil` becoming the sub-type of `List[A]` for any possible `A`. Whenever you need a list, no matter what the element type, you can use `Nil`.