# Scala - Covariance

Tags: scala, covariance, scala-generics

According to covariance definition:

> Q[+B] means that Q can take any class, but if A is a subclass of B,
>   then Q[A] is considered to be a subclass of Q[B].

Let's see the following example:

```
trait SomeA
trait SomeB extends SomeA
trait SomeC extends SomeB

case class List1[+B](elements: B*) 

val a = List1[SomeA](new SomeA{},new SomeB{})
val b = List1[SomeB](new SomeB{},new SomeC{})
```

Everything is fine, but I don't see why `List1[SomeB]` is a subclass of `List1[SomeA]`, or in other words why b is a subclass of `a`?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/why-doesnt-the-example-compile-aka-how-does-co-contra-and-in-variance-w. I read this question and answer multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, `List1[SomeB]` is subclass of `List1[SomeA]` which means you can put the first where the later is needed.

```
scala> case class List1[+B](elements: B*)

scala> val a = List1[SomeA](new SomeA{},new SomeB{})
a: List1[SomeA] = List1(WrappedArray($anon$2@3e48e859, $anon$1@31ddd4a4))

scala> val b = List1[SomeB](new SomeB{},new SomeC{})
b: List1[SomeB] = List1(WrappedArray($anon$2@5e8c34a0, $anon$1@7c1c5936))

scala> val c: List1[SomeA] = b
c: List1[SomeA] = List1(WrappedArray($anon$2@5e8c34a0, $anon$1@7c1c5936))

scala> val c: List1[SomeA] = a
c: List1[SomeA] = List1(WrappedArray($anon$2@3e48e859, $anon$1@31ddd4a4))
```

If it were invariant that would be not possible, see:

```
scala> case class List1[B](elements: B*)
defined class List1

scala> val c: List1[SomeA] = b
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List1[SomeB]
 required: List1[SomeA]
Note: SomeB <: SomeA, but class List1 is invariant in type B.
You may wish to define B as +B instead. (SLS 4.5)
       val c: List1[SomeA] = b
                             ^

scala> val c: List1[SomeA] = a
c: List1[SomeA] = List1(WrappedArray($anon$2@45acdd11, $anon$1@3f0d6038))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since all the elements in `List1[SomeB]` are subtype of `SomeA` (as `SomeB` extends `SomeA`), you can simply pass `List1[SomeB]` where `List1[SomeA]` is expected.