# List of trait in Scala

Tags: list, scala, traits

I am a bit confused about Scala traits. What is the exact meaning of

```
val myList = List[MyTrait]
```

where `MyTrait` is a trait.

Does't that mean that `myList` can contain any instance of class (`MyClass`) that mixes-in `MyTrait` ?
If so, isn't it a bit weird because `MyClass` is not a `MyTrait` (or is it ?).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/why-doesnt-the-example-compile-aka-how-does-co-contra-and-in-variance-w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, if you declare your list as a `List[MyTrait]`, it will be a container for any object that mixes-in `MyTrait`.

To go further you can even specify a class and a trait like this:

If `Animal` is a class and `Fly` a trait that define the `fly()` method.

`List[Animal with Fly]` will be a list of all the animals who can fly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
trait MySuperTrait
trait MyTrait extends MySuperTrait
trait MyOtherTrait
abstract class MyAbstractClass
class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass with MyTrait with MyOtherTrait
```

Then `MyClass` [IS A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a):

- `MyAbstractClass`
- `MyTrait`
- `MySuperTrait`
- `MyOtherTrait`
- `AnyRef` / `java.lang.Object`
- `Any`

So you can use an instance of `MyClass` anywhere where one of those types (or `MyClass` itself) is required.

Answer (score 1):

```
trait A
trait B

class C extends A with B

val aList = List[A]()
// aList: List[A] = List()

val bList = List[B]()
// bList: List[B] = List()

new C :: aList
// res1: List[A] = List(C@1124910c)

new C :: bList
// res2: List[B] = List(C@24d7657b)
```

Class `C` inherits both `A` and `B` traits. So it's not weird.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the *real* question you are asking is just this:

> If so, isn't it a bit weird because `MyClass` is not a `MyTrait` (or is it ?).

It is. `MyClass` inherits from `MyTrait`, so `MyClass` IS-A `MyTrait`.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't clear to me that a trait was actually a class. Thx.