# HashMap in scala.collection.mutable is invariant but immutable.HashMap is covariant, why?

Tags: scala

I want to extends a class with a val of mutable.HashMap[] like this:

```
class Father
class Son extends Father    

class C1{
  val m = new mutable.HashMap[Int, Father]() 
}

class C2 extends C1{
  override val m = new mutable.HashMap[Int, Son]()
}
```

And get an error:

> Error:(19, 16) overriding value m in class C1 of type
>   scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,ScalaByExample.Father];  value m
>   has incompatible type  override val m = new mutable.HashMapInt,
>   Son

I found that `immutable.HashMap` is covariant but `mutable.HashMap` is invariant. It works if replace `mutable.HashMap` with `immutable.HashMap`.

So my two questions are:

1. How can I make it works using mutable.HashMap?
2. Why did scala's author design HashMap like this?

Comment: I think you'll find this is true for all Scala collections: mutability effects type variance. The operations available on mutable collections make covariance unsafe.

Answer (score 6):

Mutable maps are invariant because writing to them wouldn't be safe otherwise. Consider for example the following function:

```
def f(o: C1) {
    o.m(42) = new Father
}
```

This method is perfectly well-typed. But if you passed in an instance of `C2` as the value for `o`, it'd break because a `Map[Int, Son]` is not allowed to contain `Father` objects. Therefore your definition of `C2` is ill-typed.

Comment: Aside - I recommend reading Daniel Spiewak's helpful answer on variance(s): http://stackoverflow.com/a/674090/409976.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The reason that immutable collections in Scala are able to be covariant is because if you want to add an element, you will actually be creating a brand new object, with a (potentially) different underlying type. That's to say the underlying type of the new map will be either the same type as in the original or a supertype, as required.

So, in your situation, if you start with an instance of *HashMap[Int,Son]* and add an object which is a *Father*, the resulting map will actually be of type *HashMap[Int,Father]*. All but one of the elements of the new map will actually be *Son* objects (*Son* is a subclass of *Father*). Only the one that you added will actually be a *Father*. But as far as the compiler is concerned, all it knows about the new map is that all elements are of type *Father*.

If, as I imagine, the types of your maps are more important to you than the mutability, then you should switch to immutable types. It's rare that you really need mutability in a collection like this.

Comment: Thanks and I am trying to use immutable.HashMap. It's a good suggestion.