# Is scala.Unit not same as ()?

Tags: scala, hierarchy

I see from Scala [hierarchy](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=scala%20hierarchy&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjni5HkmOreAhXNSH0KHWxhDEMQ_AUIDigB&biw=1680&bih=850#imgrc=7VI3GmuY3X5trM:) that `AnyVal` is super type for `scala.Unit`, `Boolean`, `Char` and other `Number` types.

```
scala> val list1 = List((),  1 ) 
list: List[AnyVal] = List((), 1)  // I see this is valid when compared with hierarchy tree.

scala> val list2 = List(Unit,  1 )
list: List[Any] = List(object scala.Unit, 1) // Why???
```

I see `list1` is of type `AnyVal` where as `list2` is of type `Any`, even though they have same data (I assume).

Is `()` not same as `Scala.Unit`? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, `()` is a value of type `scala.Unit`.  Whereas, `scala.Unit` is the companion object, so it is of type `Unit.type`.

Have a look in the REPL code below:

```
scala> (): scala.Unit
// (): scala.Unit

scala> scala.Unit
// res1: Unit.type = object scala.Unit
```

Bottom line is any object you pass to a covariant list will find the type common to the values.  See discussion in [Why doesn't the example compile, aka how does (co-, contra-, and in-) variance work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/why-doesnt-the-example-compile-aka-how-does-co-contra-and-in-variance-w)

As you discovered, the common type of `Integer` and `scala.Unit` is `AnyVal`.  The common type of `Intger` and `Unit.type` is `Any`.

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 distinct entities:

1) type `scala.Unit`

2) object `()` - the only member of the class `scala.Unit`

3) object `scala.Unit` - a companion object of `1)`. It is a member of class `scala.Unit$` - not the same as `scala.Unit`.

In your first example `()` stands for `1)`, in the second `Unit` stands for `3)`

Comment: The type of the companion object is more correctly given as `Unit.type`, as it is the singleton type associated with the value `Unit`. The fact that the class is called `Unit$` is more of an implementation detail.

Comment: @HTNW yes, you are right. But I think that digging into the difference between classes and types would be confusing in the context of the question.