# Implementing a method inside a Scala parameterized class with a covariant type

Tags: scala, generics, covariance, contravariance

I've read a few tutorials including the main Scala documentation regarding method signatures of covariant types. Suppose I have the following abstract class:

```
abstract class List[+A] {

  def head: A
  def tail: List[A]
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def add[B >: A](element: B): List[B]
  protected def printElements: String

  override def toString: String = "[" + printElements + "]"

}
```

My question concerns the signature of the `add()` method. Why is it necessary to declare it that way? We are passing in a parameter that is a supertype of A. What problem does this solve? I'm trying to understand this on an intuitive level.

Comment: If you are looking for an intuition, I find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54109658/182660) about bag of fruits interesting.

Comment: @SergGr Done, also +1 to the answer about the bag of fruits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Formal explanation

Given

```
abstract class List[+A] {
  def add(element: A): List[A]
}
```

> "This program does not compile, because the parameter *element* in `add` is of type `A`, which we declared **covariant**. This doesn’t work because *functions* are **contravariant** in their parameter types and **covariant** in their result types. To fix this, we need to flip the **variance** of the type of the parameter *element* in `add`.
>   We do this by introducing a new type parameter `B` that has `A` as a **lower type bound**".
>   -- [reference](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/lower-type-bounds.html).

### Intuitive explanation

In this example, if you `add` something to a **List**:
It must be an `A` - in this case the **List** is still a `List[A]`.
Or it must be any *subtype* of `A` - in this case the element gets *upcasted* to `A`, and the **List** remains a `List[A]`.
Or if it is another type `B`, then it MUST be a *supertype* of `A` - in this case the **List** gets upcasted to a `List[B]`. *(Note: Because `Any` is just a supertype of everything, in the worst case the **List** will be upcasted to `List[Any]`)*.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose I want to make a list of integers. And suppose, for the sake of argument, that `add` is implemented without generics.

```
def add(element: A): List[A]
```

For the sake of this example, let's suppose we have some way of producing an "empty" list.

```
def emptyList[A]: List[A] = /* some magic */
```

Now I want to make my list of integers.

```
(1 to 10).foldRight(emptyList) { (x, acc) => acc.add(x) }
```

Oops! We have a problem! When I call `emptyList`, Scala is going to infer the *most general type*, and since `A` is covariant, it's going to assume `Nothing`. That means I just tried to add an integer to a list of nothing. We *could* fix this problem with an explicit type signature,

```
(1 to 10).foldRight(emptyList[Int]) { (x, acc) => acc.add(x) }
```

But, really, that's not solving the problem. It adds nothing to readability and just requires the user to do extra work. Realistically, I should be able to append a number to a list of nothing. It's just that, if I choose to do so, I can't meaningfully call it a list of `Nothing` anymore. Hence, if we define

```
def add[B >: A](element: B): List[B]
```

Now, I can start with a `List[Nothing]` and add an `Int` to it. The thing I get out isn't a `List[Nothing]` anymore; it's a `List[Int]`, but I can do it. If I take that `List[Int]` and come along later and add a `String` to it, well I can do that too, but now I have a virtually useless `List[Any]`.

Comment: Funny thing is `(1 to 10).foldLeft(List.empty)(_ :+ _)` still doesn't compile :)

Answer (score 2):

When you declare `+A`, you're saying that, for example, `List[String]` extends `List[Object]`. Now, imagine this:

```
val ls: List[Object] = List[String]() // Legal because of covariance
ls.add(1) // Adding an int to a list of String?
```

This is only legal if the type of the List can be expanded to include arbitrary Objects, which is exactly what your add signature does. Otherwise, the existence of `add(a: A)` would imply an inconsistency in the type system.

Comment: This is the best answer.