# Covariant type A accepted in contravariant position of function argument A => B

Tags: scala, contravariance

Consider covariant type parameter `A`

```
case class Foo[+A](a: A):
  def bar(a: A) = a             // error: covariant type A occurs in contravariant position 
  def zar(f: A => Int) = f(a)   // ok
             |
          This is contravariant position. Why is it ok?

Foo(41).zar(_ + 1) // : Int = 42
```

Why is it accepted as argument to `zar` when it occurs in contravariant position in `A => Int`?

Comment: If you want to get the intution for it, think of convert `zar` to function, its "type signature" will be something like `[-[-A, +Int], Int]`. Where as `bar` will be like `[-A, +A]`. Although this is not techniclly correct, this should convey the gist of the logic.

Comment: @sarveshseri So does `-[-A, +Int]` mean `[+A, -Int]`?

Comment: Intutively but not exactly. I have noticed that this "imperfect logic" works most of the time. Think of it more from the producer/consumer and type-casting perspective and it will be clear why it works. Your `zar` takes `f` which `consumes A to produce Int` to produce something which`consumes Unit and produces Int` (or is it `consumes Nothing and produces Int` ? Not sure. what is the type of `=> Int` ?).

Comment: It is in a contravariant position in an argument which is itself in a contravariant position. Variance works like parity: twice contravariant is covariant, and any number of times covariant is also covariant.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. With `Foo[+A, +B]` then `B` is covariant, but `def zar(f: A => B)` errors with `covariant type B occurs in contravariant position in type A => B of parameter f`, so twice covariant does not seem to be covariant here.

Comment: B is in a covariant position in f which is in a contravariant position.

Comment: @sarveshseri When you say "not exactly", what is an example where logic `-[-A, +Int] mean [+A, -Int]` does not work?

Comment: I have not seen (or might have seen but never notcied) the cases where it does not work. What I mean to say is that the whole `+/-` thing for variance is just representation and so the basic arithmatic rules don't necessarily apply here. I am not sure if a proof for this exists or not. Niether am I sure that this will work for all cases. The real logic is the combination of consumer/producer semantics and related type constraints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following the idea by @sarveshseri I will provide an intuitive explanation rather than a formal one. Both because I do not know a the details of a formal one and because I hope this one would be more helpful for readers.

First some disclaimers:

1. I may have typos or some errors, please edit the answer if you notice it.
2. As mentioned above the mental model I am to describe is an approximation, what really happens at compile time and at runtime will be different.
3. During this answer I will be referring to types and classes interchangeable. This is **WRONG** and I myself have pointed this on other answers. In this case it is for simplicity of this mental model; but I recommend that after variance clicks then you mix the distinction of types and classes to that model: https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html
4. Connected to the previous point, I will be using concrete/simple types on my example. Thankfully, thanks to type erasure and parametricity what I will explain applies to type constructors and other complex types.
5. I will also be using methods and functions interchangeably, this is also **WRONG**: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#whats-the-difference-between-methods-and-functions

Now let's get to it. First let's assume that if a method accepts a `Foo` then it can only accept values of type `Foo` and nothing else, period.

Then let's assume that subtyping is actually an *"implicit"* function that *"cast"* values. So `B <: A` is just `B => A`
And let's imagine that such *"cast"* is a disguise, the value is actually the same one but seen differently *(this is basically the **Liskov** principle)*.

So, when you try to pass a `B` to a method that expects an `A` then this implicit cast will be inserted by the compiler. That way in runtime, that method receives a value that is seen like one of type `A` and not one of type `B`; but the value is still of type `B` *(actually here we would be talking about **classes** not **types**, but I hope you get the idea)*.

With that then let's see what happens to `bar` and `baz` methods of your covariant class `Foo`
Since `Foo[Dog] <: Foo[Animal]` the I can cast the former as the latter, then given `Cat <: Animal` I can also cast the former to the latter.
Finally, I could pass this `Cat` disguised as a `Animal` to the `bar` method of `Foo[Dog]` disguised as a `Foo[Animal]` but then at runtime we would be passing a `Cat` to a method that expects a `Dog` kataplum! Unless, of course, such method was always prepared for such situation.

That is why `bar` has to be defined like `[B >: A](b: B)`. Here we are saying that we can accept any `B` for which the compiler can produce the implicit cast function `A => B` *(the opposite as before, thanks to `Any` such type and such function is always possible)*. And then the implementation of `bar` should be able to work for that new type `B` and using the cast function when is required.
Which would mean that the previous example doesn't blow up at runtime, since we could have just passed the `Cat` directly without going via indirect disguises; this works because the compiler is always able to infer that `B` should be `Animal` *(the LUB of `Cat` and `Dog`)* so it would cast the `Cat` as `Animal` and would pass that to `bar` as well as the cast function `Dog => Animal`

Note, the presence of the `A => B` cast function implies that the compiler can also create the `F[A] => F[B]` function, if `F` is covariant.

Now let's see what happens to `baz`.
Again, we would cast a `Foo[Dog]` as a `Foo[Animal]` and then we would try to call `baz` with a function `Animal => Int` which should work at runtime because we do not even need the disguise at all, we could have passed such a function directly to `Foo[Dog]` because `(Animal => Int) <: (Dog => Int)` this because functions are contravariant on their inputs.

But how would this work at all? Simple, the intuition says that if I am able to process / consume / receive / use any `Animal` then I should be able to process any `Dog` since those are `Animals`, right? Let's see it how that would work with our mental model.

I have `baz(Dog => Int)` and I have `f(Animal => Int)` what the compiler can do is create a new function `g(Dog => Int) = cast(Dog => Animal) andThen f(Animal => Int)` and use `g` instead.

Hope this helps, feel free to leave any question.

Comment: I am unable to get the paragraph starting with "That is why bar has to be defined like [B >: A](b: B). Here we...."   Why do we need to establish the relationship between A and B ? B is stand alone. I see that this paragraph is explaining how to overcome the problem in the previous paragraph. But not able to get how it is solving...

Comment: @user3103957 sure you could just use `B` alone and in terms of variance it will be correct at definition site as well as at usage site the compiler would have inferred `Animal` for the disguised case. However, if you try to implement your own **List** and you try to implement the `::` method and you use just `def ::[B](b: B): List[B]` without the `B >: A` you will notice two things, first that it is impossible to implement, second that doing `cat :: listOfDogs` would return a `List[Cat]` _(assuming you force the implementation someway)_ which doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: @user3103957 so those are the 2 reasons why we use `B >: A` First to get the _"implicit"_ cast function `A => B` which also give us another one `F[A] => F[B]` _(where `F` is the covariant type being define, like `List[+A]`)_ that is used in the implementation. And also, because that way we force the compiler to find the LUB between the current type inside the covariant type and the type of the passed element. Another intuitive explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54163830/implementing-a-method-inside-a-scala-parameterized-class-with-a-covariant-type/54164135#54164135

Comment: Thanks Luis! Sorry for the delayed reply.. I spent considerable amount of time thinking about this.  Basically the usage of [B >:A], allows any sort of type to be passed to the function. The type 'Any' satisfies this. So why not we use 'Any' in place of B? Hence [B >: A] can be avoided completely.   I really appreciate your valuable time responding to my questions!!  This co/contra variance and their usage is the hardest thing I  have ever come across in any languages.

Comment: @user3103957 again let's consider this with the concrete example of prepend on `List` if you do `def ::(elem: Any): List[Any]` then if you do `val animals = myCat :: myDogs` you would get back a `List[Any]` which means we lose all the type safety of the language, even worse something as simple as `1 :: Nil` would be a `List[Any]` even worse, all lists would be `List[Any]` sine there is not a typesafe way to construct a well-typed one.

Answer (score 4):

Your class can be viewed as

```scala
trait Function1[-Input, +Result]  // Renamed the type parameters for clarity

case class Foo[+A](a: A) {
  val bar: Function1[A, A] = identity
  val zar: Function1[Function1[A, Int], Int] = { f => f(a) }
}
```

The approach taken by the compiler is to assign positive, negative, and neutral annotations at each type position in the signature; I'll notate the positions by putting + and - *after* the type in that position

First the top-level `val`s are positive (i.e. covariant):

```scala
case class Foo[+A](a: A) {
  val bar: Function1[A, A]+
  val zar: Function1[Function1[A, Int], Int]+
}
```

`bar` can be anything that's a subtype of `Function1[A, A]` and `zar` can be anything that's a subtype of `Function1[Function1[A, Int], Int]`, so this makes sense (LSP, etc.).

The compiler then moves into the type arguments.

```scala
case class Foo[+A](a: A) {
  val bar: Function1[A-, A+]
  val zar: Function1[Function1[A, Int]-, Int+]
}
```

Since `Input` is contravariant, this "flips" the classification (+ -> -, - -> +, neutral unchanged) relative to its surrounding classification.  `Result` being covariant does not flip the classification (if there was an invariant parameter in `Function1`, that would force the classification to neutral).  Applying this a second time

```scala
case class Foo[+A](a: A) {
  val bar: Function1[A-, A+]
  val zar: Function1[Function1[A+, Int-], Int+]
}
```

A type parameter for the class being defined can only be used in + position if it's covariant, - position if contravariant, and anywhere if it's invariant (`Int`, which is not a type parameter can be considered invariant for the purpose of this analysis: i.e. we could have dispensed with annotating once we got to a type which neither was a type parameter nor had a type parameter).  In `bar`, we have a conflict (the `A-`), but in `zar` the `A+` means no conflict.

The produce/consume relationship presented in Luis's answer is a good intuitive summary.  This is a partial (methods with type parameters complicate this, though I'm not totally sure how my transformation would work there...) exploration of how the compiler actually concludes that the `A` in `zar` is in a covariant position; *Programming in Scala* (Odersky, Spoon, Venners) describes it in more detail (in the 3rd edition, it's in section 19.4).