# Scala: Map of functions on sum types

Tags: scala, generics, types, contravariance

Given the following code

```
sealed trait Fruit

case class Apple(color: String) extends Fruit
case class Orange(color: String) extends Fruit

def getAppleColor(apple: Apple) = apple.color
def getOrangeColor(orange: Orange) = orange.color

val myMap: Map[String, Fruit] = Map(
"myApple" -> Apple("red"),
"myOrange" -> Orange("orange"),
)

val myMapOfFunctions: Map[String, Apple with Orange => String]  = Map(
"myAppleColorFun" -> getAppleColor,
"myOrangeColorFun" -> getOrangeColor,
)
```

Why `myMapOfFunctions` is not a `Map[String, Fruit => String]` similarly to `myMap`? I guess because it is about functions but I'd like better to understand why. Thanks!

Comment: Because `Functions` are contravariant, not covariant, on their inputs; thus `Apple with Orange => String` is the valid subtype of both functions, and `Fruit => String` is not. - What would happen if I would do this: `myMapOfFunctions("myAppleColorFun")(Orange("orange"))` the program would crash at runtime... except that it won't because it won't compile exactly for this reason.

Comment: `Apple with Orange` is not a sum type, it's an empty intersection type.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't see any way to "repair" it, because it's unclear what the `myMapOfFunctions` is supposed to do in the first place. Please reformulate your question with a clearer goal of what you're attempting to achieve, simply posting an obviously broken piece of code and stating that it's broken is not an answerable question (at least not beyond what Luis has already said: the functions in your map are not applicable to any `Fruit`, in particular they are not applicable to *all* `Fruit`).

Comment: @AndreyTyukin sorry if it's not clear. I am just trying to understand why the compiler says that the type of the map is `Apple with Orange` and not `Fruit`.

Comment: Ah, so, the `Apple with Orange` is just something that has been inferred by the compiler? Well, that's because your first function requires the input to be of type `Apple`, whereas the second function requires the input to be of type `Orange`, so these both constraints together result in the (unsatisfiable) constraint that all inputs are both `Apple`s and `Orange`s, i.e. it does not allow any inputs whatsoever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am just trying to understand why the compiler says that the type of the map is Apple with Orange and not Fruit

Okay, the good thing is that this is *"easy"* to explain.
The bad thing is that it may not be as easy to understand.

Let's take a couple of steps back, and let's simplify the code a little by using an `if` instead of a collection.

When you do something like this:

```scala
val foo = if (bar) x else y
```

The compiler has to infer the type of `foo`, for doing that it will first get / infer the types of `x` and `y`; let's call those `X` & `Y` respectively and then compute the LUB *(least upper bound)* between both, resulting in a new type `Z` which will be the type assigned to `foo`
This makes sense because `X <: Z` and `Y <: Z` and thus Liskov is respected.

> Quick note, if `X` and `Y` are the same types `A` then the LUB is just `A`
> Another quick one, if `X` is a subtype of `Y` then the LUB is simply `Y`

Let's see those applied to simple types:

```scala
val fruit = if (true) Apple(color = "red") else Orange(color = "green")
```

Here, one branch has the type `Apple` and the other `Orange` and the LUB between both is `Fruit`.
Everything has been straightforward until this point.

Now, let's spice the things up a little:

```scala
val optApple: Option[Apple] = Apple(color = "red")
val optOrange: Option[Orange] = Orange(color = "green")

val optFruit = if (true) optApple else optOrange
```

Here one branch is `Option[Apple]` and the other is `Option[Orange]`, we know that the result will be `Option[Fruit]`, but why?
Well, because `Option` was defined to be covariant on its type parameter thus `Option[Fruit]` is a supertype of both branches; and mainly the LUB.

Okay, but what happens with functions?

```scala
// Implementations do not matter.
val appleFunction : Apple => Apple = ???
val orangeFunction: Orange => Orange = ???

val fruitFunction = if (true) appleFunction else orangeFunction
```

In this case, the LUB will be `(Apple with Orange) => Fruit` ... but why?

Well, the return is easy since functions are also covariant on their returns which means the LUB will again be `Fruit`
But, why is the input not like that? Well, because functions are contravariant on their inputs, thus for a function `f` to be a subtype of another function `g`, the type of the input of `f` must be a super type of the input of `g`; i.e. it goes in the opposite order which is why it is called contravariance.

So that explains why the compiler inferred that type.
But, you may be wondering what this variance business is, why it matters, and why there is one that seems counterintuitive. But that is outside of the scope of this question & answer.
Nevertheless, I can share a couple of resources that may be useful:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUmj7jnXet4&t=53s
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1ftkK1zhxI&t=3s
- [Covariant type A accepted in contravariant position of function argument A => B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68234835/covariant-type-a-accepted-in-contravariant-position-of-function-argument-a-b/68236182#68236182)