# Why does @newtype prevent the LUB from being inferred correctly?

Tags: scala

Scala version: 2.13.5

I have the following case classes

```
  @derive(decoder, encoder, eqv, show, uuid)
  @newtype
  case class GenreId(value: UUID)

  @derive(decoder, encoder, eqv, show)
  case class Genre(
      uuid: GenreId,
      name: GenreName,
      parent: Option[GenreParentId],
      toplevel: Option[GenreTopLevelId],
      idpath: List[GenreId]
  )
```

using `newtype` and `derevo`. Any type I haven't explicitly defined can be assumed to be similar to `GenreId` wrapping either a `String` or a `UUID`.

I define the following recursive function

```
private[services] def findTopLevel(allGenres: List[Genre], parent: Option[GenreId]): Option[GenreId] = {
  parent match {
    case None => None
    case Some(parentId) =>
       val currentParent: Option[Genre] = allGenres.filter( g => g.uuid.toString() == parentId.value.toString()).headOption
       currentParent.flatMap{ n => 
         n.parent match {
            case None    => Some(n.uuid) 
            case _ @ Some(a) => 
               if(allGenres.contains((x : Genre) => x.uuid.value === a.value)){  
                   findTopLevel(allGenres, Some(GenreId(a.value)))
               }else{
                    Some(n.uuid)
               }
         }
       }
   }
}
```

This results in

```
[error] a type was inferred to be `Object`; this may indicate a programming error.
[error]                     if(allGenres.contains((x : Genre) => x.uuid.value === a.value)){
```

The root of the issue spans from the `contains[A1 >: A](elem: A1): Boolean` signature of `contains`. It has been over 12 years since people tried to understand what that type bound is doing there (some explanations offered here: [Scala: Why does Seq.contains take an Any argument, instead of an argument of the sequence type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678998/scala-why-does-seq-contains-take-an-any-argument-instead-of-an-argument-of-the) none are convincing for me as `Iterator` carries the same covariance but doesn't suffer from this fallacy). As a result doing something like `filter(...).length` or `.iterator.contains` works without any hiccups.

Then I realized there was a second part to this puzzle, the `newtype`. [Here it works when the macro is removed](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/sinanspd/eWbS5ZqsQWeFO4I2cQfQUg/1)

Knowing what the macro expands to, I am completely baffled as to why this inference drastically jumps all the way to `Object`, especially in a trivial case like this where the types are equal. Does anyone have any idea and is there a way to work around this?

Comment: You want to use `exists` rather than `contains` - and that has nothing to do with variance, or **newtype**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez First of all, thanks. Seems like being away from Scala for a year, I forgot everything :D However, I disagree this has nothing to with variance or nt. I don't see anything in `contains` 's signature that suggests that this shouldn't work. Yes, I can and I will use `exists` but is there any reason why `contains` shouldn't work? purely from an academic/curiosity point of view

Comment: It depends on what you mean with _"shouldn't work"_. You can use `contains` the way you did, it would just always return `false` so it is a bug; because you are comparing `Genres` with functions by equality. - The reason for the type signature is due variance, nobody has been thinking about that for 15 years, is confusing at first but can be explained in like 5 minutes.

Comment: Correct. It will return false because of the hashcode comparison but it should at least compile, which isn't the case. As for the explanation, do you have a link I can read. I am curious why `Seq` descendant needs this but `Iterator` can get away with it

Comment: Well, it did compile... or at least type checked. It just inferred `Any` which is correct. And then you have a compiler flag that makes the compiler warn when it infers `Any` and another that turns all warnings into errors, but the code is _"valid"_ on a vanilla setup. - About the variance explanation, if you excuse my self promotion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54163830/implementing-a-method-inside-a-scala-parameterized-class-with-a-covariant-type/54164135#54164135 - As why `Iterator` is different is because `contains` directly accepts `Any` _(not sure why)_

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I am so dumb... I passed in a predicate to contains instead of an element... Now I see what you mean. My apologies