# Generic type of class in scala

Tags: scala

How to write equivalent of java code

```
  Class<? extends Parent>  clazz = ...
```

in Scala? I need something like

```
val clazz: Class< ? <: Parent> = ...
```

but it does not works. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_basic_syntax.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic wildcards in variable declarations in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663032/generic-wildcards-in-variable-declarations-in-scala)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
val clazz: Class[_ <: Parent] = ???
```